# jquery ajax call (2)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100INR=?USD';
    var title = "jQuery";

    $.getJSON("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100INR=?USD" + "&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

```
<div id="div1">Test Page</div>
```

I am making the call and I am getting an error. You know why ? How do I make ajav calls to the  url http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100INR=?USD

Comment: What is your error message ?

Comment: That error you get...that is in the info we need to help! (I'm going to guess SOP tho)

Comment: The URL returns JSON, not JSONP. But you are telling jQuery to expect JSONP by using `callback=?`. As a result the response will be evaluated as JavaScript (that's what JSONP is), but JSON is not a valid JavaScript script, and therefore you get an error.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586003/jquery-getjson-url-data-callback

Answer (score 0):

You can't make AJAX calls cross-domain.  You will need to use something like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to make it work cross-domain.

jQuery's [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method supports JSONP requests.  If the Google API doesn't support JSONP style responses, you are out of luck.  Using a proxy, as suggest by @FelixKling, is the other option.

Comment: When adding `callback=?` to the URL, `$.getJSON` will make a "JSONP request" too. The problem is that the URL does not return JSONP. You cannot just "use" JSONP, the server side has to support it.

Comment: @Anirban: Did you read my comment? You *are already* trying to use JSONP, but since JSONP is not supported by the API, you cannot use it. The only solution is to proxy the request through your server or a CORS enabled external proxy.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yes...you are correct.  Unless the API supports JSONP responses, you are out of luck (without going through a proxy).