# in JSON, Why is each name quoted?

Tags: javascript, json

[The JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) says that JSON is an object or an array.  In the case of an object,

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  **A name is a
> string.**  ...

And later, the spec says that a string is surrounded in quotes.

Why?

Thus,

```json
{"Property1":"Value1","Property2":18}
```

and not

```json
{Property1:"Value1",Property2:18}
```

**Question 1**: why not allow the name in the name/value pairs to be unquoted identifiers?

---

**Question 2**: Is there a semantic difference between the two representations above, when evaluated in Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "in JSON"? It makes "JSON" look like a programming language.

Comment: @Bruno: You could speak of XML the same way... and sadly, some out there may well be trying to use XML as a programming language...

Comment: +1 ... it does seem like a peculiar contradiction.... "with quotes" makes it standard JSON, but won't work with `eval()` (i.e. javascript).

Comment: @bruno, no. if you expand it, it becomes "in Javascript Object Notation" which is fine

Comment: @skaffman — It will work when evaled in JavaScript.

Comment: @Bruno - JSON is a data format.  "In JSON" means - with data formatted according to the spec.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4201441/8910547, which also has a better answer than the ones here.

Comment: The [JSON5 superset spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61599957/8910547) adheres to ES5 syntax and thus supports unquoted keys amongst other things. The library has compatible `parse` and `stringify` methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any practical reason to use quoted strings for JSON keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201441/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-use-quoted-strings-for-json-keys)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Question 1: why not allow the name in the name/value pairs to be unquoted identifiers?

The design philosophy of JSON is "Keep it simple"

*"Quote names with `"`"* is a lot simpler than *"You may quote names with `"` or `'` but you don't have to, unless they contain certain characters (or combinations of characters that would make it a keyword) and `'` or `"` may need to be quoted depending on what delimiter you selected"*.

> Question 2: Is there a semantic difference between the two representations above, when evaluated in Javascript?

No. In JavaScript they are identical.

Comment: No it's not correct. CMS has the correct answer. This answer is just a nice side-effect of the real reason. Aside from being simpler to explain, it's also simpler to write a parser, since you can reuse the parse rules for strings on identifiers.

Comment: and aside from that, there's a slight semantic difference in that if an identifier happens to be a reserved word, it is interpreted as that word rather than as an identifier.

Comment: @nhnghia — Question 2 is about evaluating the source code **as JavaScript**, not JSON. `JSON.parse` is a JSON parser implemented in JavaScript, it isn't a JavaScript parser.

Answer (score 142):

I leave a quote from a presentation that Douglas Crockford (the creator of the JSON standard) gave to Yahoo.

He talks about how he *discovered* JSON, and amongst other things why he decided to use *quoted keys*:

> ....
>   That was when we discovered the
>   unquoted name problem. It turns out
>   ECMA Script 3 has a whack reserved
>   word policy. Reserved words must be
>   quoted in the key position, which is
>   really a nuisance. When I got around
>   to formulizing this into a standard, I
>   didn't want to have to put all of the
>   reserved words in the standard,
>   because it would look really stupid.
>
> At the time, I was trying to convince
>   people: yeah, you can write
>   applications in JavaScript, it's
>   actually going to work and it's a good
>   language. I didn't want to say, then,
>   at the same time: and look at this
>   really stupid thing they did! So I
>   decided, instead, let's just quote the
>   keys.
>   That way, we don't have to tell
>   anybody about how whack it is.
>
> That's why, to this day, keys are quoted in
>   JSON.

You can find the complete video and transcript [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C-JoyNuQJs).

Comment: Ummm... the *creator* of the JSON standard ?! I believe that's an overstatement. JSON is the JavaScript Object Notation and comes from the Javascript (ECMA) spec.

Comment: @Sorin: Don't confuse JSON with JavaScript Object literals. JSON is a language-agnostic data interchange format, proposed by Crockford on 2006(http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627), its grammar differs from the JavaScript Object literals (http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.5), basically by allowing only *string* keys and the values *MUST* be an *object*, *array*, *number*, *string*, or one of the following literal names: *false*, *null* *true*. Object literals in JavaScript can have keys as *Identifiers*, *String literals* or *Number literals*,  and the value can be any type of *expression*...

Comment: @CMS And the JavaScript of today allows shorthand identifiers inside object constructor expressions, e.g: `{ a }`, where property 'a' copies the value of a global or local variable 'a'.

Comment: @CMS And there's also computed keys: `{[key]: value}`

Comment: @ChristianC.Salvadó that old bclary link to ECMA-262 ultimately leads to a 404 now.  Perhaps this is a suitable replacement link? https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-object-type

Answer (score 0):

Both `:` and whitespace are permitted in identifiers. Without the quotes, this would cause ambiguity when trying to determine what exactly constitutes the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript objects can be used like a hash/hashtable with key pairs.

However if your key has characters that javascript could not tokenize as a name, it would fail when trying it access like a property on an object rather than a key.

```
var test  = {};
test["key"] = 1;
test["#my-div"] = "<div> stuff </div>";

// test = { "key": 1, "#my-div": "<div> stuff </div>" };

console.log(test.key);           // should be 1
console.log(test["key"]);        // should be 1
console.log(test["#my-div"]);    // should be "<div> stuff </div>";
console.log(test.#my-div);       // would not work.
```

identifiers can sometimes have characters that can not be evaluated as a token/identifier in javascript, thus its best to put all identifiers in strings for consistency.

Answer (score -3):

If json describes objects, then in practise you get the following

```
var foo = {};

var bar = 1;

foo["bar"] = "hello";
foo[bar] = "goodbye";
```

so then,

```
foo.bar == "hello";
foo[1] == "goodbye" // in setting it used the value of var bar
```

so even if your examples do produce the same result, their equivalents in "raw code" wouldn't.  Maybe that's why?? dunno, just an idea.

Comment: @David, variable names are not interpolated in JS when used as an object key. `{ bar: 'goodbye' }` will not set the key name to the value of `bar`, it will just be `bar`. The others are right about the reason why the spec requires quotes: it's to avoid keyword and special-character conflicts.

Answer (score -3):

I think the right answer to Cheeso's question is that the implementation surpassed the documentation.  It no longer requires a string as the key, but rather something else, which can either be a string (ie quoted) or (probably) anything that can be used as a variable name, which I will guess means start with a letter, _, or $, and include only letters, numbers, and the $ and _.

I wanted to simplify the rest for the next person who visits this question with the same idea I did.  Here's the meat:

**Variable names are not interpolated in JSON when used as an object key** (Thanks Friedo!)

Breton, using "identifier" instead of "key", wrote that "if an identifier happens to be a reserved word, it is interpreted as that word rather than as an identifier."  This may be true, but I tried it without any trouble:

```
var a = {do:1,long:2,super:3,abstract:4,var:5,break:6,boolean:7};
a.break
```

=> 6

About using quotes, Quentin wrote "...but you don't have to, unless [the key] contains **certain characters** (or combinations of characters that would make it a keyword)"

I found the former part (certain characters) is true, using the @ sign (in fact, I think $ and _ are the only characters that don't cause the error):

```
var a = {a@b:1};
```

=> Syntax error

```
var a = {"a@b":1};
a['a@b']
```

=> 1

but the parenthetical about keywords, as I showed above, isn't true.

What I wanted works because the text between the opening { and the colon, or between the comma and the colon for subsequent properties is used as an unquoted string to make an object key, or, as Friedo put it, a variable name there doesn't get interpolated:

```
var uid = getUID();
var token = getToken();            // Returns ABC123
var data = {uid:uid,token:token};
data.token
```

=> ABC123

Answer (score -3):

It may reduce data size if quotes on name are only allowed when necessary