# JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject exception

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON String structured in the following way and it throws an exception  passing it into `JSONArray timeJSONArray = new JSONArray(time);`

This is the error `Value [{"daysByte":158,"from":1020,"to":1260},{"daysByte":96,"from":1020,"to":1320}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` This is how I receive the array and I can't change it, so I'm having trouble converting it to a JSON Object instead of a JSON String which is the format it's currently in. What am I doing wrong?

```
[   
   [  
      {  
         "daysByte":30,
         "from":660,
         "to":1290
      },
      {  
         "daysByte":96,
         "from":660,
         "to":1320
      },
      {  
         "daysByte":128,
         "from":1050,
         "to":1290
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "daysByte":252,
         "from":690,
         "to":840
      },
      {  
         "daysByte":252,
         "from":1050,
         "to":1260
      }
   ]
]
```

This is the code I am working with. I'm getting the value passed in as a string

```
public ArrayList<String> getTimeList(String time){

        System.out.println("PLACES ACTIVITY " + time);
        ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            //JSONObject timeJSONObject = new JSONObject(time);
            JSONArray timeJSONArray = new JSONArray(time);
            ArrayList<LegacyTimeSpan> timeSpanList = new ArrayList<>();

            LegacyTimeSpanConverterImpl converter = new LegacyTimeSpanConverterImpl();


            for(int i = 0; i < timeJSONArray.length(); i++){

                int daysByte = timeJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("daysByte");
                int from = timeJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("from");
                int to = timeJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("to");

                System.out.println("TO " + to);

                LegacyTimeSpan timeSpan = new LegacyTimeSpan(daysByte, from, to);
                timeSpanList.add(timeSpan);

            }

            Log.d("Time span list", timeSpanList.toString());
            WeekSpan weekSpan = converter.convertToWeekSpan(timeSpanList);
            List<DayTimeSpanPair> dayTimeSpanPair = weekSpan.toDayTimeSpanPairs();
            for(int i = 0; i< dayTimeSpanPair.size(); i++){

                String timeRange = buildTimeString(dayTimeSpanPair.get(i));
                times.add(timeRange);


            }
        } catch(JSONException e){
            Log.d("PLACES EXCEPTION JSON",e.getMessage());
        }

        return times;
    }
```

Comment: Don't just show the JSON, show the code as well. Always show the code.

Comment: See my answer to the above problem , basically there two arrays one within other , hence your have to consider the arrays, Currently you are trying to put first array to an JSONObject which is not correct

Comment: `timeJSONArray.getJSONObject(i)`? You don't have a JsonObject at `i`, you have an array

Answer (score 1):

> This Code should work i think as u declare the json Format.

```
             [
                [
                  {
                  } ,{},{}             // Json Object Structure as u defined in you Question
topArray =      ],
                [  
                  {
                  },{},{}
                ]
             ]


for(JSONArray objArray : topArray){
    for(JSONObject eachObject : objArray){
   System.out.println(eachObject.get("daysByte"););
   System.out.println(eachObject.get("from");
   System.out.println(eachObject.get("to");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hi following code is working for your json I have tried. It is specific for your json not generic. so if you want you can use it.

```
try{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data); //insted "Data" pass your json Strint
       for(int i=0 ; i<jsonArray.length() ; i++){
           JSONArray internalArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
           for(int j = 0 ; j < internalArray.length() ; j++){
               JSONObject internalObject = internalArray.getJSONObject(j);
               Log.d("data" ,  internalObject.getString("daysByte"));
               Log.d("data" ,  internalObject.getString("from"));
               Log.d("data" ,  internalObject.getString("to"));
           }
       }

   }catch(Exception e){
       Log.d("data" ,"Error");
   }
}
```

Comment: If you find it useful then please mark it as answer

Comment: It won't get past the first line. That is where it throws the exception so no code executes after it.

Comment: I didn't get your comment will you please explain your problem  again

Comment: The Exception gets thrown at the line `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data)` so nothing below it will execute. It will just jump straight to the "catch"

Comment: I have tested using same json given by you it is working there might be chances you are getting different json

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays, one array within other.

You have to do like this:

```
for(JSONArray temp: timeJsonArray)
{
   // try to convert to json object
}
```

Comment: If the error is thrown at this line `JSONArray timeJSONArray = new JSONArray(time);` then how will I be able to make a for loop after it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2414332/5188230 see this, its a two dimensional JSON array

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two JSON arrays but you are accessing only one arrays that is why that error is shown

```
   try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(a);

        for (int j=0;j<jsonArray.length();j++) {

            JSONArray timeJSONArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(j);

            for(int i = 0; i < timeJSONArray.length(); i++){

                int daysByte = timeJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("daysByte");
                int from = timeJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("from");
                int to = timeJSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("to");

                System.out.println("TO " + to);


            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It is a single array only. Please check it.

Comment: @chandankumarkushwaha its a two array  see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2414332/5188230

Comment: But in overall it is added in a single array. Please check

Comment: hey man goto this link and paste your json there understand the structure first then you will be able to solve it  http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

It is a 2D Array.

```
System.out.println("days");
String content = new Scanner(new File("C:/day.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
Day[][] customDayWrap = new Gson().fromJson(content, Day[][].class);
    for (Day[] days : customDayWrap) {
        for (Day day : days) {
            System.out.println(day.getDaysByte());
            System.out.println(day.getFrom());
            System.out.println(day.getTo());
        }
    }
```

And your Day Class will be something like this.

```
public class Day {

@SerializedName("daysByte")
@Expose
private Integer daysByte;
@SerializedName("from")
@Expose
private Integer from;
@SerializedName("to")
@Expose
private Integer to;

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The daysByte
 */
public Integer getDaysByte() {
    return daysByte;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param daysByte
 *     The daysByte
 */
public void setDaysByte(Integer daysByte) {
    this.daysByte = daysByte;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The from
 */
public Integer getFrom() {
    return from;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param from
 *     The from
 */
public void setFrom(Integer from) {
    this.from = from;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The to
 */
public Integer getTo() {
    return to;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param to
 *     The to
 */
public void setTo(Integer to) {
    this.to = to;
}
```

}

I tested this (I am using Google GSON library), and I was able to successfully read it.

Answer (score 0):

After 1 hour of debugging your Json array I finally managed to figure out your actual issue. Its not only a Json Array its array inside the array.

So loop like this,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < timeJSONArray.length(); i++) {

            for(int j= 0;j<i;j++) {
                int daysByte = timeJSONArray.getJSONArray(i).getJSONObject(j).getInt("daysByte");
                int from = timeJSONArray.getJSONArray(i).getJSONObject(j).getInt("from");
                int to = timeJSONArray.getJSONArray(i).getJSONObject(j).getInt("to");
                Log.d("dataRecieved", "daybyte " + daysByte + "from " + from + "to " + to);
            }
}
```

And do others as you need.