# Serializing a C# object without surrounding quotations symbols

Tags: json, serialization, c#-4.0, json.net

In C#, how do I serialize an object with `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` without surrounding quotation marks around properties and their values.

Comment: Why would you wan to do that? It would result into invalid JSON.

Comment: because i use SerializeObject to generate script of highchart and in highchart property names and property values are not surrounded with quotation mark.

Comment: I am not familiar with highchart and its API but it seems it doesn't work with JSON because as I said quotes are required in a JSON serialized string.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree this technically creates invalid JSON and HighCharts should happily use quoted and unquoted formats in the browser, if you really want this for some reason you can do it quite easily.

Just use the `Serialize` method with a [JsonTextWriter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) and set the [QuoteName property](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_QuoteName.htm) to `false` to prevent quotes in your property names.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555096/564726