# Serialize Dictionary - how to rename key and value

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `Dictionary<string,int[]>` that I need to serialize to JSON.  Using the default formatter, I get

```
{"blah": [0,1,2,3], "yada": [0,1,2,3]}
```

What I need is something like this

```
[{ name: "blah", data: [0,1,2,3]}, name: "yada", data: [0,1,2,3] }]
```

What's the best/easiest way to achieve this?  Should I write a custom serializer class?  Or is there a different collection type that would work better than Dictionary?

Comment: So you have a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`?

Comment: Dictionary<string, int[]>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little bit of  LINQ you can easily transform your dictionary to your format:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>
    {
        {"blah", new[] {0, 1, 2, 3}},
        {"yada", new[] {0, 1, 2, 3}}
    };
var transformedData = dict.Select(e => new {name = e.Key, data = e.Value});
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transformedData);
```

Or you can create a custom `JsonConverter` which do this conversion.

Comment: excellent suggestion, thanks!  Only issue is that name and data are serialized as "name" and "data".  Any ideas?

Comment: The JSON format uses quotes around attribute names. So strictly speaking `[{ name: "blah", data: [0,1,2,3]}, name: "yada", data: [0,1,2,3] }]` **is not a valid JSON document** because the `name` and `data` are not quoted. However with some hacking JSON.net can be convinced to not generate a valid JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553516/json-net-serialize-property-name-without-quotes