# How can I convert my Dataset to Json without Quotes and Dataset name?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am converting DataSet to JSon using this code.

```
JObject jsonObject = new JObject();
string jsonString = string.Empty;

JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;
jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsResults, jsonSettings);
jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(identifier))
   jsonObject.AddFirst(new JProperty("identifier", identifier));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceType))
   jsonObject.AddFirst(new JProperty("resourceType", resourceType));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(patientId))
{
   jsonObject.AddFirst(new JProperty("patientId", patientId));
   jsonObject.AddFirst(new JProperty("status", "'{success: true}'")); 
}
jsonString = jsonObject.ToString();
```

And, it is giving me output (appending Dataset name and all the things within quotes) as;

```
{
  "TableName": [
    {
       "status": "{success: true}",
       "softwareName": "MY Software",
       "softwareVersion": "0.4.5.9",
       "TimeZone": "(UTC+12:00) City, Country"      
    }
  ]
}
```

But, I want output like this

```
{
   status: {success: true},
   softwareName: "My Software ",
   softwareVersion: "0.4.5.9",
   TimeZone: (UTC+12:00) City, Country
}
```

What is problem in above code or what modifications can I do? I don’t want to achieve my results with `jsonString.Replace("","")` or indexing approach.

Comment: Why do you use serialization to json string and later write that do not want to use.

Comment: Actually, I wan't to serialize this but, I'm having this in quotes and Dataset name @Breakermind

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes

Comment: Try create string from variables dont use json serialize string s = "{ \"Name\" : 123 "+variable+"}";

Comment: @WimOmbelets I know this, but as mentioned this is my requirement to pass this to our service provider/consumer

Comment: @Breakermind I don't wan't to build it by myself as there are still more requirements coming from our service provider and almost all of them have this syntax which they'll process further

Comment: Now I'm curious as to what they're actually requiring you to pass because it sure ain't json.

Comment: No wait strike that... It  should be emphasized, that what you end up with is, in fact, NOT json. the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) clearly states that "An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array." If they wish to process it further, let them but it's bad practice to indulge in other people's bad practice. Dare I quote Obi-Wan in this: "Who's the more foolish? The fool or the fool who follows him?"

Comment: @WimOmbelets ... Thanks for reminding about Obi-Wan quote, but, you know _might is right_ . The man dealing with us there is Technically NON-TECHNICAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably avoid it as it is not compliant with the JSON standard.

That said, if you need to go ahead with it there's a great solution here by Christophe Geers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555096/4636912

> Using the Json.NET library you can achieve this as follows:
>
> ```
> [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)] public class ModalOptions {
> [JsonProperty]
> public object href { get; set; }
>
> [JsonProperty]
> public object type { get; set; } }
> ```
>
> When serializing the object use the JsonSerializer type instead of the static JsonConvert type.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> var options = new ModalOptions { href = "file.html", type = "full" };
> var serializer = new JsonSerializer(); var stringWriter = new
> StringWriter(); using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
> {
>    writer.QuoteName = false;
>    serializer.Serialize(writer, options);
> } 
> var json = stringWriter.ToString();
> ```
>
> This will produce:
>
> ```
> {href:"file.html",type:"full"}
> ```
>
> If you set the QuoteName property of the JsonTextWriter instance to false the object names will no longer be quoted.

Comment: And, how not to append DataSet name?