# How to get rid of quotes in JSON file property name using NewtonSoft JSON.Net Serialize()?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Instead of:

{ "type": "FeatureCollection" }
I need to get
{ type: "FeatureCollection" }

[Here](https://blog.bitscry.com/2017/10/23/serializing-json-values-without-quotes/) is a nice article how to do this for value. But I need to remove quotes for property names...

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Json.Net - Serialize property name without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7553516/3744182).  Of course the "JSON" thereby written will not be well-formed.

Comment: Unless you have a REALLY good reason for doing this... don't!

Comment: a really good reason for this is GraphQL which doesn't support quote marks on propertynames for some reason.