# How to convert model list to json highchart map data

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I have a model list of data to map chart. But the map chart accepts value format like this:

> data: [{id: 'London', lat: 51.50, lon: -0.12}]

But the below code produce a data like this

[image]

The Id value is in double quote what I need is single quote 'London' and it should not display like that '&quot'. The sample chart with data can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/flight-routes/

Model

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class ShipmentLocationModel
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public decimal lat { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public decimal lon { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
List<ShipmentLocationModel> LocationList = new List<ShipmentLocationModel>();
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
    writer.QuoteName = false;
    serializer.Serialize(writer, LocationList);
}
ViewData["LocationList"] = stringWriter;
```

View

> data: @ViewData["LocationList"]

Comment: hi @xdtTransform it is different my problem is the double quote.

Comment: You are using [the right method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553516/json-net-serialize-property-name-without-quotes) to serialize your List with out the quoted name

Comment: @xdtTransform yes but the id value "London" should be 'London' single quote only

Comment: Someone messed with the standard. It's not Json anymore. More seriously expecting double quote in the value or you can assume a simple remplace should be enought?

Comment: Btw, the fiddle work with everything quoted?

Comment: @xdtTransform it works now. double or single quote works. thank you

Comment: Js exemple trend to use a mix of `'` and `"`. Those people seems to be afraid of escaping char. Most of the time they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@Html.Raw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) method:

```
data: @Html.Raw(ViewData["LocationList"])
```

Comment: Hi the output was still double quote but it is not '&quot' anymore data: [{id: "London", lat: 51.50, lon: -0.12}]

Comment: sorry it works now that is weird single or double quote works now. thank you.