# Remove Quotes From Json Property Key In C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Currently I have a json object

```
  [DataContract]
public class Menu
{

    [DataMember(Name = "state")]

    public string state { get; set; }


    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "type")]

    public string type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "icon")]
    public string icon { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "badge")]
    public List<BadgeItem> badge { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "saperator")]

    public List<Saperator> saperator { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "children")]
    public List<ChildrenItems> children { get; set; } 

  }
```

After serialize object it give

```
[
   {
      "state":"Application Security",
      "name":"Application Security",
      "type":"#",
      "icon":"av_timer",
      "badge":null,
      "saperator":null,
      "children":[
         {
            "state":"apps",
            "name":"Users Administration",
            "type":null,
            "child":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

But I dont want any single/double quotes around properties like

```
[
   {
      state:"Application Security",
      name:"Application Security",
      type:"#",
      icon:"av_timer",
      badge:null,
      saperator:null,
      children:[
         {
            state:"apps",
            name:"Users Administration",
            type:null,
            child:null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Please let me know how to do this?

Comment: What serializer are you using?  If you are using [tag:json.net] then this is a duplicate of [Json.Net - Serialize property name without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7553516/3744182).  As noted in the answer there, be aware that the result is not well-formed JSON.

Comment: what you want is not valid json - `INVALID JSON (RFC 8259)`

Comment: I am using  string s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(menuItems); where menuItems are list of class

Comment: no @SelimYıldız this does not solve my problem

Comment: Sure looks like it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pDU8Az