# ASP.NET MVC 3 Serializing to JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, json

I've got an `ICollection<T>` of POCO like this:

```
public class SearchJsonModel
{
   public string label { get; set; }
   public string category { get; }
}
```

In my Razor view, i serialize it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jsonArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

But the output is this:

```
var jsonArray = [
   {"category":"Names","label":"Joe"},
   {"category":"Names","label":"John"}
];
```

Which is causing problems because of the quotes around the properties.

I need to access the properties of each JSON object, so I would expect it to be like this:

```
var jsonArray = [
   {category:"Names",label:"Joe"},
   {category:"Names",label:"John"}
];
```

That way i can do something like this:

```
$.each(jsonArray, function(index, item) {
   var x = item.category;
});
```

What am i doing wrong? Am i using the wrong method to encode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This JSON is valid (checked in [JSONLINT](http://jsonlint.com/)). The quotes should be there.

You can get the category values like this without any problem

```
$(function(){
   var data=[
   {"category":"Names","label":"Joe"},
   {"category":"Names","label":"John"}
];

    $.each(data,function(index,item){
          alert(item.category);
    });        

});​
```

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/DKnBh/

Comment: /me slaps head. Was a ordering problem with my encoding and script to consume it. Sorry for wasting everones time. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is standard JSON and shouldn't cause a problem.

See here for more info: [in JSON, Why is each name quoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067974/in-json-why-is-each-name-quoted).