# JSON key names?

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON Spec - does the key have to be surrounded with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)

Which is the correct syntax?

`{ key: "value" }` or `{ "key": "value" }`?

I've seen it both ways and in my tests both work, but I'm just curious which one is syntactically correct?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067974/in-json-why-is-each-name-quoted

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON requires keys to be quoted.  JavaScript does not.  So for JSON, your second example is correct.

Comment: JavaScript does not, so long as the key is appropriate for a JavaScript label (alphanumeric, initial alpha, a few other other things).

Comment: To expand on @Malvolio.  You also cannot have Javascript reserved words without quotes.  You can't have { undefined : "value" }, as an example.  I usually just include the quotes to keep it consistent.

Comment: @RyanO'Neill: The spec *(ECMAScript 5 anyway)* lets you have reserved words without quotes. Just some older browsers didn't allow it. And `undefined` is actually not reserved. It's a valid identifier.

Comment: @user1689607 -- if you write something like `{ function : 6, undefined : "value" }` you deserve all the terrible things that will undoubtedly happen to you!

Comment: Not sure, exactly, but I have have faith in code karma.  What goes around comes around.

Comment: Notwithstanding from the aforementioned browser quirks, nothing terrible will happen. No need for FUD.

Answer (score 1):

They are both valid notation for a javascript object. Only the fully-quoted second version is valid JSON.

See [the spec](http://www.json.org/) and [this web-based linter](http://jsonlint.com/).