# advantage of snake_case over camelCase in JSON for REST

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Taken from https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design#downcase-paths-and-attributes

> Downcase attributes as well, but use underscore separators so that
>   attribute names can be typed without quotes in JavaScript, e.g.:
>
> service_class: "first"

What does it mean by "attribute names can be typed without quotes"?

Comment: You've tagged this question with `json`, so I wanted to point out that, if you are using JSON, your names in the name-value pairs must always be quoted.  That is a requirement for valid JSON ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068074/1281907 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid Javascript literal:

```
{ foo_bar: 'baz' }
```

This isn't:

```
{ foo-bar: 'baz' }
```

The latter must be:

```
{ 'foo-bar': 'baz' }
```

That's all it's talking about; the preceding paragraph referred to *"dash-separated path names"* and followed by saying you shouldn't use dashes in JSON. It's not snake vs. camelCase, it's snake vs. "dash-case".

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
{ foo-bar: 1 }
```

You'll get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error since the "-" is mistaken as a subtraction operator:

```
{ foo - bar : 1 }
```

Then you need quotes to indicate that this is a property name:

```
{ "foo-bar": 1 }
```

If you use underscores instead of dashes, there is no ambiguity:

```
{ "foo_bar": 1 }
{ foo_bar: 1 } // This also works
```