# What is wrong with the following JSON data

Tags: json

JSON  -

```
    [   
      {
        "pagename":"1",
        "url":"sadadsad",
        "group":"ad"
      },
      {
        "pagename":"2",
        "url":"sasdsad",
        "group":"eng"
      },
      {
        "pagename":"3",
        "url":"thfgv",
        "group":"pd"
      },
      {
        "pagename":"4",
        "url":"tuyi",
        "group":"pd"
      },
      {
        "pagename":"5",
        "url":"popop",
        "group":"pd"
      }
    ]
```

Error: Parse error on line 2:
...           {         pagename:"1",
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Edit: With this rectified JSON data when I am printing the length, it's coming out to be 486, looks like some stray characters are getting added, how can I resolve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put pagename and all other var names in quotes also

```
 [   
      {
        "pagename":"1",
        "url":"sadadsad",
        "group":"ad"
      },
```

If you want to know why the quotes are needed, have a look at this answer: [in JSON, Why is each name quoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067974/in-json-why-is-each-name-quoted#2068074)

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is as follows

```
[
      {
        "pagename":"1",
        "url":"sadadsad",
        "group":"ad"
      },
      {
        "pagename":"2",
        "url":"sasdsad",
        "group":"eng"
      },
      {
        "pagename":"3",
        "url":"thfgv",
        "group":"pd"
      },
      {
        "pagename":"4",
        "url":"tuyi",
        "group":"pd"
      },
      {
        "pagename":"5",
        "url":"popop",
        "group":"pd"
      }
    ]
```

Be sure to verify your JSON [here.](http://json.parser.online.fr/) The errors are highlighted in black.