# JSON.parse not having the expected behaviour

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get a `json` request, sent by `post`, and do the `JSON.parse` on it. But this error happens:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 2
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at :1:19

The code below reproduces the error:

```
const string = '{ msg_reject: \'Rejeitado porque sim\', accept: 1, photo: \'FSADKJK23B1\' }'
const json = JSON.parse(string)
```

And that's the way I'm sending it in my `post`

`{ msg_reject: 'Rejeitado porque sim', accept: 1, photo: 'FSADKJK23B1' }`

Is there something wrong in the way I'm sending it?

Comment: this is not a valid json so that why you are getting this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in JSON, Why is each name quoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067974/in-json-why-is-each-name-quoted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON string is not formatted correctly, you will have to add double quotes `"` for keys & values as:

```
const string = '{ "msg_reject": "Rejeitado porque sim", "accept": 1, "photo": "FSADKJK23B1" }';
```

There are many online parser available where you can validate your JSON string, I generally use https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser to verify my JSON whenever it requires.

Answer (score 25):

Properly formatted JSON strings have `"` double quotes around each key and each string value.

```js
const string = '{ "msg_reject": "Rejeitado porque sim", "accept": 1, "photo": "FSADKJK23B1" }';
const json = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

While sending in post, Stringify the object first,
Use JSON.stringify(object) and send, while retrieving JSON.parse should work fine