# JSON to String without adding quotes to keys

Tags: jquery, json, export, key-value

I am building a web-application (using Javascript/jQuery) that generates JSON configuration files.

At the end the applications should convert the generated JSON to a string so that it can be copied by the user?

At the moment I am doing a simple `JSON.stringify()`, but this adds quotation to both keys and values. In order to get the configuration files to work it is necessary that the keys are exported without quotes (unless stated).

For example, `"id": "ezdzdz"` should be printed as `id: "ezdzdz"` unless its actually written as "id" in the JSON.

Thanks, all help is much appreciated!

Comment: If it's JSON and not a native Javascript object, you have to quote the key names I believe.

Comment: In JSON syntax, the quotes are mandatory. They may be optional in Javascript itself, but for it to be valid JSON, it needs to have the quotes.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes

Answer (score 5):

If it's JSON and not a native Javascript object, you have to quote the key names.

See: [JSON Spec - does the key have to be surrounded with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Embedding a JSON object in Javascript without quotes on keys is valid. It isn't valid JSON, but it is valid Javascript. Useful for stub data in unit tests for example.

I wrote a tool to do that called JSON Beautifier. Here it is:
http://www.csvjson.com/json_beautifier

Comment: This is nice, but it still quotes the keys even if the box is checked on an array of objects.

Comment: Indeed. A bug to fix. I'll reply here when it's fixed.

Comment: Now fixed. Here is the demonstration. http://www.csvjson.com/json_beautifier/d7b87615362b761067d6b5c7979e0605