# backbone.js not updating id of model object after save, why not?

Tags: backbone.js

I have been trying out backbone.js and have been stymied when I create a new model object then call model.save(). I am expecting the backbone.js default behavior to update the model object with the id from the database  but it is not. Is this not supposed to happen? I have verified that I am getting a post with the attributes in json format. My server saves the json to a table and then returns the json with a new id field to backbone.js. Is this correct?  Should my server return the entire new object or just the id or what?

```
//contents of the POST from backbone.js
  { "text":"this is a test" }

//reply from my server
  { id:"15", text:"this is a test"  }
```

My sample code is below

```
var SQLRow = Backbone.Model.extend({
 table:"",
 urlRoot:'db',
 url:function () {
    return "/" + this.urlRoot + "?table=" + this.table + 
                 "&id=" + this.attributes.id;
   }
});

var Xtra = SQLRow.extend ({
   table:'Xtra'
});

var row = new Xtra({
  text: "this is a test" 
});

alert(row.url());
row.save()
alert("row:" + row.get("id"));
```

Comment: What does the response look like that's returned from the save call?

Answer (score 6):

Tough to tell from your post.  Two ideas :

1) the response from the server isn't successful  What does your save call return ?

2) Your  "id" attribute is named something other than ID.  To account for the different name add the following to your model :

```
   idAttribute  : "MyModelsID",
```

**EDIT**

You're likely facing a timing issue, where the alert fires before the ID has returned.   Instead of your last two lines try this :

```
row.save( null, 
              { 
                 success : function(model, response) { alert(model.get('id'); } 
               }
         );
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

As @mu_is_too_short mentioned, another way is to listen for the change even on the model and respond to the event. (i was just trying to keep the answer as close to your code as possible).  But something like the following *pseudo code* should get you started...

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
           ....
           initialize : function () {
                this.collection.bind('change',  this.SOME_LISTENING_FUNC    );

             }
  });
```

OR, if you're in a collection/view-less world something like this creates a listenr ...

```
row.on('change',  function() {  /* do stuff */ }, this);
```

Comment: Or bind a `"change"` handler to the model and pick up the result of the `save` that way. Backbone is an event driven framework, trying to mash it into a serial model doesn't work that well (this part is mostly for Cjolly).

Comment: @muistooshort - so we meet again moo.  Thanks for the alternative, I incorporated some pseudo code into the answer.

Comment: There was two problems with the code. First the json format returned by the server also needs the keys of the attributes quoted ( ie. { id: "ax" } really should be { "id":"ax" }. After I made that change I was in business; however, my alert immediately after the save would likely never show the true nature of the object as the save is an asynchronous ajax call and we would always get to the alert before the ajax and backbone.js handling completed. Adding a change handler as **mu is to short** above suggests is the correct way to go:

Comment: @Cjolly - not sure how i missed the quoting.  I stumbled across that very issue yesterday.  JSON spec requires attributes to be quoted. http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Double_Quotes#Double_Quotes

Comment: @Cjolly: You can use a `success` callback or a `"change"` handler depending on the specific situation; a success callback is better for a one-time check, a `"change"` handler is better if you're interested in the property changing no matter what causes it to change. I thought the missing quotes were just a copy'n'paste thing; your server code should have a JSON encoding library of some sort.

Comment: And we'll probably meet a few more times. And I'm still not angry :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on one comment of [Cjolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036289/cjolly) in the answer above.

It is essential for making the `Backbone.Model.save([attributes],[options])` successful in assiging the model with the newly generated model's id from the server, that the server returns the model's `id` in a JSON string like this `{ "id" : <the id> }`. (note it is `"id"` and not `id`).

In essence backbone rightly expects a JSON string and in contrast to how objects may be defined in Javascript without quoted keys, **JSON requires the object keys to be quoted** (see [JSON Spec - does the key have to be surrounded with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes))

Since according to Cjolly's comment this has been the essential problem, I want to hightlight this solution in an second answer. Partially because I was hit by the very same problem and only by reading througth the comments I was able to receive the insight.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and what I've found is that my `validate` function of the saved model actually invalidates the model returned from the back end. That's why my fields were not updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a little outtimed, but today I had the same missing id.
It turns out, that the server just sends a Header 'Location' with a redirect containing the new id, but dosen't return the persisted object.
Adding the object to the response was the solution.
It seems, that not returning the object is standard behavier with Roo(Spring) generated Json-Controllers.