# Commas in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>

(function() {

$('html').addClass('js');

var contactForm = {

    container: $('#contact'),          <-- THIS COMMA

    init: function() {
        $('<button></button>', {
            text: 'Contact Me'
        })
            .insertAfter('article:first')
            .on('click', this.show);
    },  <---------------------------------- AND THIS COMMA

    show: function() {
        contactForm.container.show();
    }
};

contactForm.init();

})();

</script>
```

In the above script, I noticed:

`container: $('#contact'),`

Is that one way to declare a variable? Doing the following breaks the script:

`var container = $('#contact');`

Also, what is with the commas after the init function and the container variable (if it is a variable)?

Comment: This is Javascript object syntax and is not specific to jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This way you declare an object:

```
var contactForm = {
    // properties:
    property1 : value,
    property2 : value,
    property3 : value,

    // methods:
    method1 : function() {
        // ...
    },
    method2 : function() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

You can find more information about JavaScript objects in [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) ...and in the comments below :)

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what exactly is an object? I possess 0 Object Oriented programming knowledge. Is it like a function? Sorry if this question is dumb.

Comment: @eveo that's a big question.  Here's an abstract (not specific to js) example.  Look at your keyboard.  That's an object.  The idea of a keyboard is a "class", and the specific instance of that class is an "object".

Comment: @eveo, I'd suggest you start from [MDN's Javascript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), it will help you get a good grasp at the language and its practical uses.

Comment: Perfect article @KyleTrauberman, not sure why you edited it out. Thank you very much. I'll check out your link too Frédéric Hamidi. Thanks guys. Here's the link for anyone who see's this thread after that Kyle Trauberman linked. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml

Comment: @eveo, I didn't post a link, someone else posted that link.

Answer (score 3):

That block of code (beginning with `var contactForm = {`) is declaring an object using object literal notation. Commas separate the different key-value pairs in the object literal notation.

```
var obj = { key1: value1, key2: value2 };
```

Comment: Nope, this is not JSON notation. [JSON requires quotes around keys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949449/464709).

Comment: I never realized there was a difference.  I always thought the quotes were just optional.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Commas are used to separate name/value pairs when defining objects:

```
var newObj = {
  name: value,
  another_name: another_value
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are `key:value` pairs of the object `contactForm` you defined separated by commans

```
var obj = { key1 : value1, 

            key2 : value2

            method1 : function(){
              // definition
            },
            method2 : function(){
              // definition
            }
}
```

The thing that confused me in my early days is that what is `function(){....}` doing inside a variable(in this case an object) definition until I discovered functions are objects too in js which may not be the same case in language you have used earlier .

and this function `function(){....}` without name is called a anonymous function.

Here's a good thread on anonymous function [Why do you need to invoke an anonymous function on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work)

Answer (score 1):

That is called Object literal notation.

Which is basically a **Comma-Separated list of name/value pairs**, wrapped in curly braces.

Advantage of this notation is that all data within the braces are encapsulated and not defined  globally which avoids conflicts with other scripts or libraries.