# Getting a 400 Error on Ajax call with JSON

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I'm not sure what's wrong with the way I'm doing this...
I get a 400 Error saying it's a bad request, but I can't find anything wrong with my syntax.

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/my_project/rest/runs/1234?token=moo',
        type : 'POST',
        data: { job_position : JSON.stringify(38) },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(html) {
        }
    });
```

The receiving controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/runs/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody boolean myMethod(@PathVariable String userId, @RequestParam("token") String authenticationToken, @RequestBody @Valid Long job_position){
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you stringify that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not actually sending JSON in your request, jQuery will convert your object to a query string. To prevent this stringify it yourself.

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/my_project/rest/runs/1234',
        type : 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ job_position : 38, token: 'moo' }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(html) {
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your data part missing quotes?
 data: { "job_position" : JSON.stringify(38) }

Just a thought.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes  says it is a good practice to place quotes and also to guard against reserved words.

Comment: It is missing quotes, and as radashk mentioned, it's not mandatory. But I have added it now just to be 100% safe.

Answer (score 2):

`/my_project/rest/runs/1234?token=moo` - it's GET request sintax

make
`url : '/my_project/rest/runs/1234'`
and
`data: { "job_position" : JSON.stringify(38) , "token" : "moo"}`

so full request look like

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/my_project/rest/runs/1234',
        type : 'POST',
        data: { "job_position" : 38, "token" : "moo"},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(html) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get this in my request payload: "job_position=26&token=moo"
I also changed my controller, so that I have a single response object that contains a token and a job position.