# Code to add subcategories to dropdown not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a form for  adding  products to a site.
The form contains 2 dropdown boxes, one for categories and one for subcategories. When you choose a category in the first the second should be populated with the subcats associated to it. Cats and subcats are from 2 mysql tables.
The categories are loaded into the first box ok, but when i choose one no subcats get loaded to the second dropdown!!

Here is my form and ajax to load the subcats

```
<form class='adminform1' action='add_products.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='image_upload_form' id='image_upload_form'>
            <?php
               include '../inc/categorydropdown.php';
                ?>
               <span class='formheading'>Add Product</span><br /><br />
               <p><b>Choose Image</b><br /><input name="image_upload_box" type="file" id="image_upload_box"  /></p>
               <b>Name</b><br /><input type=text name="aname" /><br />
               <b>Description</b><br /><textarea rows="12" cols="40" name="adescription"></textarea><br />
               <b>Price</b><br /><input type=text name="aprice" /><br />
               <b>Product Code</b><br /><input type=text name="acode" /><br />
               <p><label for="cat">Category</label>
               <select name="cat" id="cat">
                  <?php echo $op;?>   
               </select><br />
               <label for="subcat">Subcategory</label>
              <select name="subcat" id="subcat"> </select></p>
              <br />
              <br />
              <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Add Product' />
              <input type='hidden' value='new' /><br />

        </form>
       <script>
         //bind category dropdown change event
         $('#cat').change(function(){
            getSubCat();
         });
         //change subcat dropdown
        function getSubCat(){
           cat = $('#cat').val();
           $.post("../inc/subcat.php", { cat: cat }).done(function(data) {
              $('#subcat').html(data);
           });
        }
        //run on page load
        getSubCat();
      </script>
```

Here is my php to produce the subcats for sending to the ajax code.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php':
if(isset($_POST['cat'])){
$cat = intval($_POST['cat']);
$query = "SELECT subcat_id, subcategory FROM `subcategories` WHERE cat_id = $cat";
$result = $link->query($query) or die('error');
$subcatOps = '';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $subcatOps .= "\n\t<option value='{$row['subcat_id']}'>{$row['subcategory']}</option>";
    }

}
echo $subcatOps;
?>
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Check your console for errors and analyze the AJAX call in the Network Tab of your browser's Dev Tools, also I would suggest you use the `success` callback to your ajax call instead of `done` and implement a `error` callback to handle well... errors

Answer (score 0):

@koala_dev is correct about how you should go about debugging. But from a glance and assuming that your $.post call is hitting the correct URL, `{ cat: cat }` should be `{ 'cat': cat }`.

Keys in JSON have to be quoted to avoid requiring another escape for reserved keywords: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes