# Servicestack json allow unquoted properties

Tags: json, servicestack, json.net

Is it possible to tell servicestack to allow unquoted properties in JSON?

I have a lot of JSON that I need to send to a service which doesn't have quoted properties - this would help a lot if it can be bound without quoted parameters.

I have this:

```
{
  color: "blue",
  size: 14
}
```

Servicestack wants this:

```
{
  "color": "blue",
  "size": 14
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, JSON keys must be in quotes, as it is a string. What you are displaying here is just javascript object  notation.

[JSON Spec - does the key have to be surrounded with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)

Comment: that's what JSON is no?

Comment: @iwayneo FYI: this answer is correct. Valid JSON requires quotes for strings and keys in object literals.

Comment: @Brad M: I can understand his confusion...JSON actually stands for JavaScript Object Notation.