# select2 on success retrieve newly created tag id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

In select2 I have tags loaded by AJAX, if the tag is not found in the db then the user has the option to create a new one. The issue is that the new tag is listed in the select2 box as a term and not as the id (what select to wants - especially becomes a problem when loading the tags again if the user wants to update since only the term and not the id is stored in the db). **How can I, on success of adding the term, make it so that select2 recieves the ID and submits the ID instead of the tag name/term?**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var lastResults = [];
$("#project_tags").select2({
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Please enter tags",
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    },
    ajax: {
        multiple: true,
        url: "framework/helpers/tags.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: function(term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    },
    createSearchChoice: function(term) {
        var text = term + (lastResults.some(function(r) {
            return r.text == term
        }) ? "" : " (new)");
        return {
            id: term,
            text: text
        };
    },
});
$('#project_tags').on("change", function(e) {
    if (e.added) {
        if (/ \(new\)$/.test(e.added.text)) {
            var response = confirm("Do you want to add the new tag " + e.added.id + "?");
            if (response == true) {
                alert("Will now send new tag to server: " + e.added.id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'framework/helpers/tags.php',
                    data: {
                        action: 'add',
                        term: e.added.id
                    },
                    success: function(data) {

                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Removing the tag");
                var selectedTags = $("#project_tags").select2("val");
                var index = selectedTags.indexOf(e.added.id);
                selectedTags.splice(index, 1);
                if (selectedTags.length == 0) {
                    $("#project_tags").select2("val", "");
                } else {
                    $("#project_tags").select2("val", selectedTags);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

Heres part of the switch that does the adding

```
case 'add':
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $new_tag = escape($_GET['term']);
        if (Nemesis::insert('tags', 'tag_id, tag_content', "NULL, '{$new_tag}'")) {
            // we need to send back the ID for the newly created tag
            $search = Nemesis::select('tag_id', 'tags', "tag_content = '{$new_tag}'");
            list($tag_id) = $search->fetch_row();
            echo $tag_id;
        } else {
            echo 'Failure';
        }
        exit();
    }
    break;
```

UPDATE: I've done a bit of digging, and what confuses me is that the select2 input does not seem to store the associated ID for the tag/term (see below). I know I could change the attribute with the success callback, but I don't know what to change!

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "doing something screwy here"? What exactly is happening? In your data option, try `data: { term: e.added.id, action: 'add' }` and then remove the `?action=add&term=' + e.added.id + ''` portion of the url option.

Comment: Yea exactly.. I did that but reverted to the way I have it now because in devtools for chrome you can clearly see nothing is being added to the end of the url and consequently the db (just posts to tags.php). However it works in the above part.

Comment: Well you are using `type: "POST"` which means the variables will NOT be added to the end of the URL. Instead, in Chrome Dev Tools look under the 'Headers' tab of the ajax call and expand the 'Form Data' section to view the term and action variables passed in the POST. If you want to see the variables in the URL, use `type: "GET"`. Also, it looks like in your PHP code you are testing whether the request is of type GET, so you will want to make your AJAX call and that logic match.

Comment: Ah I copied it from another example and forgot to remove that, removed it and now its working fine. Thanks! Any idea regarding my question?

Comment: @Alex is it possible to you to share the full n final code. As i am also planning to use this.

Comment: @404 here is the final class: http://pastebin.com/3jfS4tVG

Comment: Here is the class setup: http://pastebin.com/PB1H2C1r

Comment: @Alex thanks!!! i will try and let you know the outcome. I am using final class. one question. Do i need to create any other file while using it. like db.php or fetch.php to fetch the data from database.

Comment: @Alex I am still trying and didn't make it work. My question is do i need to use both class file (final class & class setup). How can i implement in webpage. do i need to create html/php file for the same. Your script is quite advanced and it will going over my head.

Comment: @Alex few questions - what would be the db structure. Where is the db connect file reference. how to use it in html/php file. i am trying but it is quite hard to make it working for me.

Comment: I'm using my own custom db class (see: Nemesis in the script) but it essentially just runs the query. That is pretty simple stuff. But yea you will need your own database connection so you can run the mysql commands. Setup is not a class, but rather a means to initialize the class (which you do on the page where you want to run select2), you will also need to php include the TagIt class on that page. The parameters in the setup are fairly easily, the first one just means the name of your tags database table.

Comment: This is what the tag db looks like http://imgur.com/pDHyzAL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have said, you can replace that value, and that is what my solution does. If you search the Element Inspector of Chrome, you will see, bellow the Select2 field, an input with the id `project_tags` and the `height` of `1`.

The weird thing is that the element inspector of Chrome does not show you the values of the input, as you can see below:

[image]

However, you do a `console.log($("#project_tags").val())` the input has values (as you see in the image).

So, you can simply replace the text of the new option by the id, inside the `success` function of the ajax call placed within the `$('#project_tags').on("change")` function. The `ajax` call will be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'framework/helpers/tags.php',
    data: {
        action: 'add',
        term: e.added.id
    },
    success: function(tag_id) {
        var new_val = $("#project_tags")
                        .val()
                        .replace(e.added.id, tag_id);
        $("#project_tags").val(new_val);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Please be aware that this solution is not bullet proof. For example, if you have a tag with the value `1` selected, and the user inserts the text `1`, this will cause problems.

Maybe a better option would be replace everything at the right of the last comma. However, even this might have cause some problems, if you allow the user to create a tag with a comma.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: awesome man got it working. i see what you mean in that its not bullet proof, but the situations in which those possibilities would happen are slim to none. still if you can think of a way that I can subvert it, possibly on the back-end. im open to suggestions!

Comment: @milz this question is quite old however, if you have any working example for the same as i am looking for some kickstart.

Comment: @milz if possible could you please advise me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231584/jquery-select2-duplicate-tag-getting-recreated