# jQuery select2: duplicate tag getting recreated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I asked a question earlier today ([jquery select2: error in getting data from php-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216302/jquery-select2-error-in-getting-data-from-php-mysql)). However, I am trying to fix it and doing that now I am getting bit strange issue. I am not sure why it is happening like this.

Below is the JavaScript code.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-6">       
      <input type="hidden" id="tags" style="width: 300px"/>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var lastResults = [];

$("#tags").select2({
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Please enter tags",
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    },
    ajax: {
        multiple: true,
        url: "fetch.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
      data: function(term) {
                        return {q: term};
                    },
                    results: function(data) {
                        return {results: data};
                    }, 

    },
    createSearchChoice: function (term) {
        var text = term + (lastResults.some(function(r) { return r.text == term }) ? "" : " (new)");
        return { id: term, text: text };
    },
});

$('#tags').on("change", function(e){
    if (e.added) {
        if (/ \(new\)$/.test(e.added.text)) {
           var response = confirm("Do you want to add the new tag "+e.added.id+"?");
           if (response == true) {
              alert("Will now send new tag to server: " + e.added.id);
              /*
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/someurl&action=addTag',
                   data: {id: e.added.id, action: add},    
                   error: function () {
                      alert("error");
                   }
                });
               */
           } else {
                console.log("Removing the tag");
                var selectedTags = $("#tags").select2("val");
                var index = selectedTags.indexOf(e.added.id);
                selectedTags.splice(index,1);
                if (selectedTags.length == 0) {
                    $("#tags").select2("val","");
                } else {
                    $("#tags").select2("val",selectedTags);
                }
           }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is the php code (**fetch.php**)

```
<?php 
// connect to database 
require('db.php');

// strip tags may not be the best method for your project to apply extra layer of security but fits needs for this tutorial 
$search = strip_tags(trim($_GET['q'])); 
//$search='te';
// Do Prepared Query 
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tid,tag FROM tag WHERE tag LIKE :search LIMIT 4");

// Add a wildcard search to the search variable
$query->execute(array(':search'=>"%".$search."%"));

// Do a quick fetchall on the results
$list = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Make sure we have a result
if(count($list) > 0){
   foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array('id' => $value['tid'], 'text' => $value['tag']);                
   } 
} else {
   $data[] = array('id' => '0', 'text' => 'No Products Found');
}

// return the result in json
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**select2 version is 3.5**

Above code is able to send/receive request from database by using fetch.php.

Problem is in my database there are two records **test** & **temp** when I tag any one of them it create new tag.

It should work like this: *if database have value then it won't create the new tag with same name.*

[image]

### Update

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it is working now. I would like to thanks @alex & @milz for their support.
Here is the full n final code. Now duplicate tags are not creating. However, i am working to add tag in database.

**php/html file**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="hidden" id="tags" style="width: 300px"/>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var lastResults = [];

$("#tags").select2({
    multiple: true,
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Please enter tags",
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],//[","],
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    },
    ajax: {
        multiple: true,
        url: "fetch.php",
        dataType: 'json',
      //  type: "POST",
       data: function(term,page) {
                        return {
                            term: term
                           };
                    },
                    results: function(data,page) {
                         lastResults = data;                       
                          return {results: data};

                    }, 
    },
    maximumSelectionSize: 3,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
createSearchChoice: function(term) {
    console.log($(this).attr('data'));
    var text = term + (lastResults.some(function(r) {

     console.log(r.text);
      console.log(term);
      return r.text == term
    }) ? "" : " (new)");

    return {
      id: term,
      text: text
    };
  },
});

$('#tags').on("change", function(e){
    if (e.added) {
        if (/ \(new\)$/.test(e.added.text)) {

           var response = confirm("Do you want to add the new tag "+e.added.id+"?");
           if (response == true) {
              alert("Will now send new tag to server: " + e.added.id);
              /*
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/someurl&action=addTag',
                   data: {id: e.added.id, action: add},    
                   error: function () {
                      alert("error");
                   }
                });
               */
           } else {
                console.log("Removing the tag");
                var selectedTags = $("#tags").select2("val");
                var index = selectedTags.indexOf(e.added.id);
                selectedTags.splice(index,1);
                if (selectedTags.length == 0) {
                    $("#tags").select2("val","");
                } else {
                    $("#tags").select2("val",selectedTags);
                }
           }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is the php file to get the data from database.
**fetch.php**

```
<?php 
// connect to database 
require('db.php');

// strip tags may not be the best method for your project to apply extra layer of security but fits needs for this tutorial 
//if(isset($_GET)){
$search = strip_tags(trim($_GET['term'])); 

// Do Prepared Query 
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tid,tag FROM tag WHERE tag LIKE :search LIMIT 4");

// Add a wildcard search to the search variable
$query->execute(array(':search'=>"%".$search."%"));

$list = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($list) > 0){
   foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array('id' => $value['tag'], 'text' => $value['tag']);            
   } 
} else {
   $data[] = array('id' => 'No Products Found', 'text' => 'No Products Found');
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

It took lots of time. Almost 3 days. I hope it will save someone efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Tags need an id and a text. The issue you're facing is that your text doesn't match the id.

So, even if you write the same text, Select2 thinks the new text is a new option because the id don't match.

To solve your issue, you need to set the id with the same value as the text. Change the foreach of your `fetch.php` to the following:

```
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array('id' => $value['tag'], 'text' => $value['tag']);                
}
```

**Update:**
You also need to update the variable `lastResults` to avoid the duplication of tags with the same text. When you bind select2, you need to change the `results` property of `ajax` to this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606092/select2-with-createsearchchoice-uses-newly-created-choice-for-keyboard-entry-eve/16857898#16857898):

```
ajax: {
    multiple: true,
    url: "fetch.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: function(term) {
        return {q: term};
    },
    results: function(data) {
        lastResults = data.results;
        return {results: data};
    }, 
},
```

Note the `lastResults = data.results;`. Without this, the `lastResults` variable is always empty and, when the `createSearchChoice` function is executed, it will always return a new tag.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Now there is another issue. If i am writing test in the search box then it is showing me test there but it create a new tag like this test (new tag). i am attaching screenshot.

Comment: one more thing if i use comma (,) then it is creating duplicate tag. if i use tab or enter then it won't

Comment: @404 I've created a demo with static data (the `temp` and `test`) so you can see how it's working. As for the creation of tags through enter, tab or comma, it's working on my fiddle. I guess you should try to make it work with static data first and then connect select2 to PHP and MySQL. Check the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/milz/avqfjc33/

Comment: i checked your fiddle and it also had same issue as mine. try to enter test in search box and after that press comma you will see test new will get created.

Comment: @404: Yes, I see that. It seems that you took part of [this answer's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16857898/908174) but remove a important part of it. On the `createSearchChoice`, you're using `lastResults`, but this value is always empty. Take a look at the answer were you took the code and check the usage of `lastResults` on the `results` of `ajax`. I updated my fiddle to assume the options and it's working correctly (https://jsfiddle.net/milz/avqfjc33/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. However, i didn't figure out how to use lastresults. i didn't copied from there but somewhere else. data: function(term,page) {
                        return {
                            term: term
                       
                        };
                    },
                    results: function(data,page) {
                        lastResults = data.results;
                                                 
                         return data;
                    },

Comment: Thanks for your support. It didn't helped. i tried as you suggested but it is not showing data from database. I can see data is coming from db but it is not showing. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined. $.select2.createSearchChoice @ tag.php:84(anonymous function)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102839/discussion-between-404-and-milz).

Comment: Finally it is working. now i am working on adding tag in database.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the changes as in the select2.min.js (v4.0.6-rc.1) code snippet below

section 1

```
c.on("results:select", function() {
                    var a = e.getHighlightedResults();
                    if (0 !== a.length) {
                        var c = b.GetData(a[0], "data");
                        "true" == a.attr("aria-selected") ? e.trigger("close", {}) : e.trigger("select", {

                        //custom select2 tagging
                        if(a.attr("aria-selected")){
                            c.id = c.id + 1;
                        }
                        e.trigger("select", {
                            data: c
                        })

                        //"true" == a.attr("aria-selected") ? e.trigger("close", {}) : e.trigger("select", {
                        // e.trigger("select", {
                        //     data: c
                        // })

                    }
                })
```

section 2

```
this.on("query", function(b) {
                    a.isOpen() || a.trigger("open", {}), this.dataAdapter.query(b, function(c) {
                        //custom select2 tagging
                        let searchInput = $(".select2-search__field").val();
                        searchInput = {results: [{id: searchInput, text: searchInput}]};
                        a.trigger("results:all", {
                            data: c,
                            data: searchInput,
                            query: b
                        })
                    })
                })
```