# How to set default id as 0 for new tags

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

How to set a default id to 0 for the tags which is not from the list ?

```
[DEMO LINK][1]
```

[LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bkr6XBUq1CvYx0fXpQV?p=preview)

In the above e.g if we select from existing, then it comes with id (1 or 2 or 3), but if add new Tag and press enter then the id becomes as text, i want id to set as o for new tag OR not from the list.

How to do that?

Comment: Your plunker appears to be broken

Comment: _Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/master/src/select2.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled._

Comment: @Malkus updated my plunkr, please chk

Comment: @Jai updated my plunkr, please chk

Answer (score 0):

CreateSearchChoice should be what you are looking for

here is a similar SO i asked a while ago [select2 createSearchChoice id from post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089070/select2-createsearchchoice-id-from-post/25209305#25209305)

```
createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
    if ($(data).filter(function () {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            // if not found in current list
            // return {id:term, text:term}

            return {
            id: term,
            text: $.trim(term) + ' (new tag)'
            };

},
```

Note i am setting the id to new text term, you could set it to a concatenated value like -1/term, then parse it out later, but term must be included in the ID for this solution

then on the change event, i determine whether the id is numeric (exists already). if its not numeric (added in the createsearchchoice) I go through my process of posting to the database of tags

```
.on("change", function(e) {
    if (e.added) { //is it added from select2
    if (isNumeric(e.added.id)){ //did it already exist or createsearchchoice
        add(e.added.id); //it already existed, just add it to the tag list
        } else { //id was created on the fly, post to the database and return a tag id
            $.post('handlers/tags.ashx', { 
               operation:"select2createtag", 
               //because its not numeric, we know id = new tag text
               text: $.trim(e.added.id)} ,   
               function(data){
               //set the added id to the id you just returned from sql
                e.added.id = data.id;
                //...do something else, like then add the new tag to the item

                });
              };
            };
```

if you dont want to post to ajax, have your server-side evaluate your input items, and any tags that are non-numeric for id , follow the same idea above

[I updated your Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cFsZGpIQ5TJK32SV5l1L?p=preview)

Comment: Thx , i've tried your code and some extend its working. I mean i get the ID as 0 but it only allows me to enter one new tag, after that its not adding new tags. I've updated my plunkr, plz chk

Comment: and its not allowing to put id as 0, thats why i've kept '00' in plunkr.

Comment: i updated the answer and the Plunker...note that you probably will want to change the static assignment of tags if you want it to be dynamic