# How to produce JSON with unquoted keys?

Tags: php, json

This is what I want to do. I would like to change the key inside the associative array of this below

```
array("role" => "annotation");
```

This code above returns a result of in JSON

```
{"role": "annotation"}
```

I would like this output above to be like this output below

```
{role: "annotation"}
```

Comment: Strings values are always quoted, so `role` isn't a valid array key, while `'role'` is

Comment: If you check the [JSON documentation](http://www.json.org/) you'll see that the last example is actually not valid JSON, the specifiers on the right should be quoted string.

Comment: Hey, Any reason why you want key without quote?

Comment: I need it for the Google Bar Chart. I already made the AJAX for it and I need to use the annotation role in it. My purpose is to make distance between the bars in the bar chart.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$a = array($role => "annotation");

echo $a = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', json_encode($a));
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you but how can I modify it if it's inside an array already like this? 

[['sample1', 'sample2', {"role": "annotation"}]]

I would like it to be like this

[['sample1', 'sample2', {role: "annotation"}]]

please help.

Comment: $a = array(array('sample1', 'sample2',array('role' => "annotation")));
echo $a = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', json_encode($a));

Answer (score 4):

[JSON string keys are always quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949449/362536).  If they weren't, they wouldn't be compatible with the JSON standard.  There is no way to change this behavior with `json_encode()`.

If you want JavaScript object literals, which allow for unquoted string keys, you will need to write your own code to output that, which I don't recommend.

Answer (score -1):

@Kapil

```
preg_replace('/"([^\s"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $json);
```

Is a safier option.