# Validating JSON using GSON in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using GSON to validate a string which is in JSON format:

```
String json="{'hashkey':{'calculatedHMAC':'f7b5addd27a221b216068cddb9abf1f06b3c0e1c','secretkey':'12345'},operation':'read','attributes':['name','id'],'otid':'12'}";
Gson gson=new Gson();
Response resp = new Response();
RequestParameters para = null;
try{
    para = gson.fromJson(json, RequestParameters.class);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("invalid json format");
}
```

Its doing good but when I remove the quotes like below, I have removed from hashkey:

```
"{hashkey':{'calculatedHMAC':'f7b5addd27a221b216068cddb9abf1f06b3c0e1c','secretkey':'12345'},operation':'read','attributes':['name','id'],'otid':'12'}"
```

It's still validating it as a proper JSONformat and not throwing any exception and not going in catch body. Any reason why it is doing so? How would I solve this?

RequestParameters class:

```
public class RequestParameters {
    HashKey hashkey;
    String operation;
    int count;
    int otid;
    String[] attributes;

}
```

Comment: Please post your RequestParameters class as well so we can see what fields it is mapping to.

Comment: See also [How to check if JSON is valid in Java using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233898/how-to-check-if-json-is-valid-in-java-using-gson/47890960#47890960) on working gson strict parsing workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Now it will treat second quote as part of hashkey. Have a look at below json string that is get back from the object.

I tested it at [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
  "hashkey\u0027": {
    "calculatedHMAC": "f7b5addd27a221b216068cddb9abf1f06b3c0e1c",
    "secretkey": "12345"
  },
  "operation\u0027": "read",
  "attributes": [
    "name",
    "id"
  ],
  "otid": "12"
}
```

sample code:

```
String json = "{hashkey':{'calculatedHMAC':'f7b5addd27a221b216068cddb9abf1f06b3c0e1c','secretkey':'12345'},operation':'read','attributes':['name','id'],'otid':'12'}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
    Object o = gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);
    System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(o));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("invalid json format");
}
```

> Is there quote needed around JSON string against keys?

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)

Comment: Actually in my case i am not storing it in a string but i am using rest client to send uri to rest service and i send body as following:

{"hashkey":{"calculatedHMAC":"f7b5addd27a221b216068cddb9abf1f06b3c0e1c","secretkey":"12345"},"operation":"read","attributes":["name","id"],"otid":"12"}

It is then stored in a string in rest service as rest service is receiving it as a String but when i print it. It is printed same:

{"hashkey":{"calculatedHMAC":"f7b5addd27a221b216068cddb9abf1f06b3c0e1c","secretkey":"12345"},"operation":"read","attributes":["name","id"],"otid":"12"}
So here no single quotes.

Comment: same thing applies for double quotes as well.