# How to check if JSON is valid in Java using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have method that have to check if JSON is valid, found on [How to check whether a given string is valid JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-a-given-string-is-valid-json-in-java) but it doesn't work.

```
public static boolean isJson(String Json) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            gson.fromJson(Json, Object.class);
            return true;
        } catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If I use this method with some string it always returns true. For example:

```
System.out.println(renderHtml.isJson("{\"status\": \"UP\"}"));
```

it gave me `true`, and

```
System.out.println(renderHtml.isJson("bncjbhjfjhj"));
```

gave me `true` also.

Comment: are you looking for schema validation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found solution but using `org.json` library, according to [How to check whether a given string is valid JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-a-given-string-is-valid-json-in-java/10174938#10174938)

```
public static boolean isJson(String Json) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(Json);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            try {
                new JSONArray(Json);
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now random looking string `bncjbhjfjhj` is `false` and `{"status": "UP"}` is true.

Comment: What is the size of the biggest JSON you expect to validate with this method?

Comment: Not big. It's for reading of healthchecks from Springboot applications. 3 or 4 levels of nesting.

Comment: They have a special JsonParser for this: http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2

Answer (score 12):

You should not use `Gson` to make such validation:

- `Gson` is an object that performs *deserialization* therefore it deserializes *entire* JSON as an object in memory.
- `Gson`, and I didn't know it, may be not very strict for some invalid JSONs: `bncjbhjfjhj` is deserialized as a `java.lang.String` instance. Surprise-surprise!

```java
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

private static final String VALID_JSON = "{\"status\": \"UP\"}";
private static final String INVALID_JSON = "bncjbhjfjhj";

System.out.println(gson.fromJson(VALID_JSON, Object.class).getClass());
System.out.println(gson.fromJson(INVALID_JSON, Object.class).getClass());
```

Output:

> class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
>   class java.lang.String

What you can do here is using `JsonReader` to read incoming JSON token by token thus making if the given JSON document is syntactically valid.

```java
private static boolean isJsonValid(final String json)
        throws IOException {
    return isJsonValid(new StringReader(json));
}

private static boolean isJsonValid(final Reader reader)
        throws IOException {
    return isJsonValid(new JsonReader(reader));
}

private static boolean isJsonValid(final JsonReader jsonReader)
        throws IOException {
    try {
        JsonToken token;
        loop:
        while ( (token = jsonReader.peek()) != END_DOCUMENT && token != null ) {
            switch ( token ) {
            case BEGIN_ARRAY:
                jsonReader.beginArray();
                break;
            case END_ARRAY:
                jsonReader.endArray();
                break;
            case BEGIN_OBJECT:
                jsonReader.beginObject();
                break;
            case END_OBJECT:
                jsonReader.endObject();
                break;
            case NAME:
                jsonReader.nextName();
                break;
            case STRING:
            case NUMBER:
            case BOOLEAN:
            case NULL:
                jsonReader.skipValue();
                break;
            case END_DOCUMENT:
                break loop;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError(token);
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch ( final MalformedJsonException ignored ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then test it:

```
System.out.println(isJsonValid(VALID_JSON));
System.out.println(isJsonValid(INVALID_JSON));
```

Output:

> true
>   false

Answer (score 7):

While it might be weird to you

```
"bncjbhjfjhj"
```

Is indeed valid json, as it is a string, and its the only string.

According to the not so new [JSON RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt)

> A JSON text is a serialized value. Note that certain previous
>   specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an
>   array. Implementations that generate only objects or arrays where a
>   JSON text is called for will be interoperable in the sense that all
>   implementations will accept these as conforming JSON texts.

Comment: Despite you're correct on that, the OP is actually asking why `Gson` does not reject `bncjbhjfjhj` (no quotes) as an invalid JSON document.

Comment: Because it is valid JSON ? its just a plain string

Comment: The OP was testing it with `renderHtml.isJson("bncjbhjfjhj")`, not with `renderHtml.isJson("\"bncjbhjfjhj\"")`.

Comment: @WilomGfx you right. I found solution by using `org.json` library.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv i am aware of that, but you're giving GSON a String, which will be deserialized to a java.lang.string. Which kinda makes sense according to the spec

Comment: @WilomGfx Because `Gson` does not work the same as a more low-level Gson component `JsonReader` does. Check both `bncjbhjfjhj` and `"bncjbhjfjhj"` with any JSON linter.

Answer (score 7):

I was quite surprised that while [`GsonBuilder#setLenient`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setLenient--) states

> By default, Gson is strict and only accepts JSON as specified by [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). This option makes the parser liberal in what it accepts.

It appears to be flat-out lie as it is actually always lenient. Moreover, even any call to [`JsonReader.setLenient(false)`](https://github.com/google/gson/issues?q=lenient) is completely ignored!

After some browsing in [numerous](https://github.com/google/gson/issues?q=lenient) [related](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/372#issuecomment-187766986) [issues](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/499) and [several](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/804) [rejected](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/795) [pull](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/902) requests "due to legacy compatibility reasons" I've at last found https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1208 with sensible workaround:

> JakeWharton commented on 15 Dec 2017

> You can call getAdapter(type).fromJson(gson.newJsonReader(input))
> instead of just fromJson(input) to get strict parsing. We should
> really deprecate all of the fromJson methods and add new versions that
> are strict by default.
>
> The reason is bad decisions long ago that we can no longer change ;(

So here is pure Gson solution for strict json object parsing with extensive test case.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class JsonTest {

    private static final TypeAdapter<JsonObject> strictGsonObjectAdapter = 
            new Gson().getAdapter(JsonObject.class);

    public static JsonObject parseStrict(String json) {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233898/how-to-check-if-json-is-valid-in-java-using-gson/47890960#47890960
        try {
            //return strictGsonObjectAdapter.fromJson(json); // this still allows multiple top level values (
            try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(json))) {
                JsonObject result = strictGsonObjectAdapter.read(reader);
                reader.hasNext(); // throws on multiple top level values
                return result;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testStrictParsing() {
        // https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient-boolean-
        // Streams that start with the non-execute prefix, ")]}'\n".
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("){}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("]{}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("}{}"));
        // Streams that include multiple top-level values. With strict parsing, each stream must contain exactly one top-level value.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{}{}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{}[]null"));
        // Top-level values of any type. With strict parsing, the top-level value must be an object or an array.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict(""));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("null"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("Abracadabra"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("13"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("\"literal\""));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("[]"));
        // Numbers may be NaNs or infinities.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"number\": NaN}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"number\": Infinity}"));
        // End of line comments starting with // or # and ending with a newline character.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{//comment\n}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{#comment\n}"));
        // C-style comments starting with /* and ending with */. Such comments may not be nested.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{/*comment*/}"));
        // Names that are unquoted or 'single quoted'.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{a: 1}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{'a': 1}"));
        // Strings that are unquoted or 'single quoted'.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\": str}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\": ''}"));
        // Array elements separated by ; instead of ,.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\": [1;2]}"));
        // Unnecessary array separators. These are interpreted as if null was the omitted value.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\": [1,]}"));
        // Names and values separated by = or => instead of :.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\" = 13}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\" => 13}"));
        // Name/value pairs separated by ; instead of ,.
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\": 1; \"b\": 2}"));

        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\": }"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\": ,}"));
        assertThrows(JsonSyntaxException.class, () -> parseStrict("{\"a\": 0,}"));

        assertTrue(parseStrict("{} ").entrySet().isEmpty());
        assertTrue(parseStrict("{\"a\": null} \n \n").get("a").isJsonNull());
        assertEquals(0, parseStrict("{\"a\": 0}").get("a").getAsInt());
        assertEquals("", parseStrict("{\"a\": \"\"}").get("a").getAsString());
        assertEquals(0, parseStrict("{\"a\": []}").get("a").getAsJsonArray().size());
    }

}
```

Note the this ensures single top level object. It's possible to replace `JsonObject.class` with `JsonArray.class` or `JsonElement.class` to allow top level array or [null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526995/is-null-valid-json-4-bytes-nothing-else).

The code above parses JSON to `JsonObject` DOM representation.

The code below does strict parsing into custom POJO with conventional fields mapping.

```
// https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1208
private static final TypeAdapter<Pojo> strictGsonAdapter = new Gson().getAdapter(Pojo.class);

public static Pojo parsePayment(String json) throws IOException {
    return strictGsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: Note that test above uses [`Assert.assertThrows`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests/41019785#41019785) from JUnit 4.13-beta-3.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
public static boolean isJson(String Json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        gson.fromJson(Json, Object.class);
        Object jsonObjType = gson.fromJson(Json, Object.class).getClass();
        if(jsonObjType.equals(String.class)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to verify that the input is valid JSON without using the parsed JSON data, then the easiest and probably most performant solution to this is:

```java
public static boolean isValidJson(String input) {
    try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(input))) {
        reader.skipValue();
        return reader.peek() == JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note however that even a `JsonReader` in non-lenient mode allows certain JSON strings which are not valid per specification, see the [documentation for `JsonReader.setLenient(boolean)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient(boolean)) which lists those cases.

All other solutions using either `Gson` or `JsonParser` will probably not work correctly because those classes are lenient by default and this behavior cannot be configured.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Verify if its a valid json object or array.
 *
 * Note:- strings or primitives are not considered as valid json.
 *
 * @param json  string to verify
 * @return      true if string is a valid json, otherwise false
 */
private boolean isValidJson(String json) {
    try {
        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
        if (!jsonElement.isJsonObject() && !jsonElement.isJsonArray()) return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```