# Gson parse invalid json with a quotation mark

Tags: android, json, gson

I use Gson in my android project.
And I try to parse object like

{
"field1":"value1",
"field2":value2"
}

It's invalid json. But I'm not getting an exception. I'm getting valid object with field2 = null

Comment: Might possible that `Gson` is filling the void here ..

Comment: Yes, but it is not valid json object (it can be checked on https://www.json.org/json-en.html or https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: realistically your problem lies with `It's invalid json. ` take the raw response you get and parse it yourself

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce that `field2` is `null`, for me it is `value2"`; with the following Gson usage:

```java
new Gson().fromJson("{ \"field1\":\"value1\", \"field2\":value2\" }", CustomClass.class);
```

Unfortunately due to legacy reasons Gson is 'lenient' by default and therefore accepts JSON which would considered malformed by a strict parser. This is also discussed a bit in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/372).

As workaround you can obtain the respective `TypeAdapter` with [`Gson.getAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#getAdapter(java.lang.Class)) and then call one of its methods to perform the deserialization. See also [this related answer about JSON validation with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890960).