# Trying to remove quotes from arrayed JSON keys

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, json

I have this array of javascript objects (which are actually musical notes) that are generated in my javascript front-end. In order to store it, I had to run javascript `JSON.stringify(objectArray)`before throwing it into a hidden input, but that automatically encases all my keys in double quotes like so:

```
[
  {"class":"barline","symbol":"standard","barline":true,"newSystem":true},
  {"class":"note","rhythm":"half","duration":0.5,"symbol":"flag","hand":"R","newbar":true,"rebel":false},      
  {"class":"note","rhythm":"half","duration":0.5,"symbol":"flag","hand":"R","endbar":true,"rebel":false},
  {"class":"barline","symbol":"standard","barline":true},
  {"class":"note","rhythm":"half","duration":0.5,"symbol":"flag","hand":"R","newbar":true,"rebel":false}
]
```

Before filtering my params in Rails, I run `JSON.parse(params[:score][:notes])` to turn it from a string into a proper JSON array for storage in MongoDB (I'm specifically using Mongoid)

I know it's normally proper procedure to keep keys in quotes in most cases, but I like using the dot notation for keys to grab values in all my JS.

Should I switch my JS to reference everything with brackets, or can you think of a simple function that would quickly parse out the keys' quotes before sending to the hidden input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Spec - does the key have to be surrounded with quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)

Comment: I don't know understand well the reason but you can remove the quotes whit a simple replace like `varStringified.replace(/\"/g, "");` This is solve your answer?

Comment: The quotes will not prevent you from using dot notation.

Comment: infused - Thanks, I did read that one.
Nothing - This take out all the double quotes, they need to remain for all values. I'm just trying to remove them from the keys.
Travis, I tested and I think you're right on this one. So I'm guessing the brackets are really just good to throw in a variable or something as the key name. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking to do something similar to pass linting, and this regex finds all quotes before semicolons in the string:

`"(\w*)":`

And replace that with just the text, excluding the quotes:

`$1:`