# Array of Javascript Objects To Php Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to decode this array of object to Php array, 
I used json_decode() but that returned Null

```
$a = "[
{
    id:1,
    name:'rajan',
    class:10
},{
    id:2,
    name:'amrit',
    class:12
},{
    id:3,
    name:'arun',
    class:11
}
]";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into? You have a string right now - so it is not decodable.

Comment: The lack of quote marks around key values such as `id`, `name` and `class` suggests that this is not valid json

Comment: I tried to decode above string using json_decode, but that does not worked out!!

I need to know how can I convert above string to php array

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, I know there is no quotes on the key of each objects, that's the reason I am getting null on the json_decode but the key of the json object may not be Quoted thats doesnot mean thats invalid json!!!

am I right??  I have to decode in such case :(

I spend couple of hour on it!!

Comment: So where is this json coming from? The optimal solution is to fix it at source, not to put in some workround/monkeypatch to resolve it.... and RFC4627 is quite clear about the need for quote marks: `The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
   family of programming languages.  __A string begins and ends with
   quotation marks.__`

Comment: An alternative might be a preg_replace that searches for unquoted strings before a `:` and wraps them in quotes before you do your json_decode

Comment: @MarkBaker What's I posted is array of JavaScript Object, and that's why I was unable to use, json_decode!!

I was wrong saying it JSON data, perhaps i should have told you array of javascript object

What will be the easiest way to make it php array then!!!

Comment: So you are starting out with a string of Javascript that you'd like php to parse? is it possible to have the source of this javascript string convert it to JSON using JSON.stringify() ?

Comment: @khartnett I don't have access to that!!

Comment: `$.ajax({
            url: '{{ base_url('home/data_save') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {'data':JSON.stringify(na)}
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function (data) {

        });`

I just got the code, and this resulting the above data on the backend

using 

`$req = $this->input->post('data');
print_r($req);`

and the format of **na** is located on [http://jsfiddle.net/mydvzud6/](http://jsfiddle.net/mydvzud6/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid, which is why json_decode is returning null.

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token i`

http://json.parser.online.fr/

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

I have also fixed your JSON:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name":"rajan",
    "class":10
},{
    "id":2,
    "name":"amrit",
    "class":12
},{
    "id":3,
    "name":"arun",
    "class":11
}
]
```

---

Fixing your broken JSON with code:

```
$replace_keys = preg_replace("/(\w*):/i", '"$1":', $a);
$fix_values = preg_replace("/:'(\w*)'/i", ':"$1"', $replace_keys);
```

You can then use `$replace_keys` in `json_decode`. I am not sure if this is the best method, as small variations in your json could break it, but it fixes it with the example provided.

---

Full code to fix JSON:

```
$a = "[
{
    id:1,
    name:'rajan',
    class:10
},{
    id:2,
    name:'amrit',
    class:12
},{
    id:3,
    name:'arun',
    class:11
}
]";


$replace_keys = preg_replace("/(\w*):/i", '"$1":', $a);
$fix_values = preg_replace("/:'(\w*)'/i", ':"$1"', $replace_keys);

die($fix_values);
```

Comment: Not really an answer to his question.

Comment: @Daan Answer has been expanded.

Comment: its actually its array of object, object may not have quotes around the keys!! and in the case what I supposed to do, wrap the key with the quotes and then use json_decode :(

Comment: I know If I add the Quotes its will work, but that's not the actual solution is it???

Comment: Being Honest that's array of Objects :) in javascript  @Jono20201

Comment: In pure Javascript you don't need the quotes around the keys unless using a reserved word, but when using the JSON format, it does require quotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes

Comment: Then there is not any predefined function on php to make php array of javascript array of objects right!! 
@khartnett

Comment: @Jono20201 This is Not the Exact Solution for what I have asked!! :(

Comment: @Rajan Updated answer with a way to fix provided JSON example to 'answer the question'.

Comment: @Rajan It'd be appreciated if you could 'accept' the answer if this is the full solution.