# How to properly uplevel a json key in java? Why is the json not changing?

Tags: java, json

I have an array "myarray" like this:

```
[{
   name: John,
   age: {
     years:18
   },
   computer_skills: {
     years:4
   },
   mile_runner: {
     years:2
   }
}]
```

How do I uplevel it properly? Using minimal-json, I do the following:

```
JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.readFrom(myarray);
for( JsonValue val : jsonArray) {
    JsonObject myObj = val.asObject();
    for( JsonObject.Member myMember : myObj ) {
        if(myMember.getValue().isObject()) {
            JsonObject myMemberObj = myMember.getValue().asObject();
            for (JsonObject.Member nestedMember : myMemberObj) {
                if(nestedMember.getName().equals("years")) {
                    myObj.set(myMember.getName(), nestedMember.getValue());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

The last line when I print out my jsonArray, it looks as if nothing has changed whatsoever. What am I doing wrong? I want to end up with the following:

```
[{
   name: John,
   age: 18
   computer_skills: 4
   mile_runner: 2
}]
```

I tried using this: https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json. Alternatives are welcome. I want to not have to create a model object that contains key value pairs for every single key value in my object within "myarray". I am used to python where everything is simple to access and replace.

Comment: why not using jackson?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by jackson, but I dont want to define a "Model" object that maps to all my values. I am used to python where I can just access things directly. Not sure if jackson would be simpler for what I am trying to do, I am open to anything. I heard org.json was "slower" than some alternatives, not sure if true or not.

Comment: Gson from Google seems to be not the worst one, I myself used JsonLib in my university project, there is also json-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching I found out that your json array is invalid, there are quotes missing on at least the keys (See [why do you need the quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)). Look at the same code you used but with modified input for 'myarray':

```
String myarray = "[{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":{\"years\":18},\"computer_skills\":{\"years\":4},\"mile_runner\":{\"years\":2}}]";
    JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.readFrom(myarray);
    for( JsonValue val : jsonArray) {
        JsonObject myObj = val.asObject();
        for( JsonObject.Member myMember : myObj ) {
            if(myMember.getValue().isObject()) {
                JsonObject myMemberObj = myMember.getValue().asObject();
                for (JsonObject.Member nestedMember : myMemberObj) {
                    if(nestedMember.getName().equals("years")) {
                        myObj.set(myMember.getName(), nestedMember.getValue());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

This code prints:

```
[{"name":"John","age":18,"computer_skills":4,"mile_runner":2}]
```

what is the expected result.