# SyntaxError: Illegal character in colsole

Tags: arrays, json

I am getting a syntax-error: `illegal character on this line`, does anyone have any idea what this could be?

```
{pIconImg:"/blob/958/893/transparent_128x1,0.png", pIconImgAltTxt:"null", pName:"Gogo Unlimited Mobile",  pCode:"ASMARC5555", pPriceDollar:"49", pPriceCents:"95", pBuyUrl:"/gbp/pickpass.do?execution=e6s1&_eventId=buy&productCode=ASMARC5555&quantity=1&requesterType=gbp&lang=en_US&curr=USD", pShortDescr:"Unlimited access on domestic Gogo equipped flights with <a href="#" id="parAir">participating airlines</a>.", pLongDescrUrl:"/gbp/pickpass.do?execution=e6s1&_eventId=more&productCode=ASMARC5555"}
```

[image]

Comment: the double quotes inside the <a href="#" id="parAir"> are actually escaped using \ where the short description is being served, if that helps

Comment: we need a bit more context about what this object is and how it is being used... it seems the issue may be that when it is brought into the page from where it is server the characters are being un-escaped and then the elements placed into objects with improper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Its good practice to use quotes around the key.
If you're interested to know why, check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)

Regarding the problem you're having, once I quoted the keys, json validation passed (jsonlint.com)

```
{
    "pIconImg": "/blob/958/893/transparent_128x1,0.png",
    "pIconImgAltTxt": "null",
    "pName": "Gogo Unlimited Mobile",
    "pCode": "ASMARC5555",
    "pPriceDollar": "49",
    "pPriceCents": "95",
    "pBuyUrl": "/gbp/pickpass.do?execution=e6s1&_eventId=buy&productCode=ASMARC5555&quantity=1&requesterType=gbp&lang=en_US&curr=USD",
    "pShortDescr": "Unlimited access on domestic Gogo equipped flights with <a href=\"#\" id=\"parAir\">participating airlines</a>.",
    "pLongDescrUrl": "/gbp/pickpass.do?execution=e6s1&_eventId=more&productCode=ASMARC5555"
}
```