# How to properly set an empty map to a parsed json (which is a new map)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch

I have declared this empty map `mapA = {}` but for some reason when I set it to a parsed json `mapA = parsedJSON` would result in an error of same or duplicate keys.

The json which I fetched is something like this `[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]`, just to clarify...this is a json right? Cause its also kind of an array right?

But I fetched this as a json string and then parse it and then I receive the error I mentioned.

However, `mapA = [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]` works for me but this is hard coded. What part is wrong in here actually?

**EDIT1**:

Here is a sample data which I used

```
[{"location_id":1,"flight_location":"KUL","description":"Kuala Lumpur","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":2,"flight_location":"KIX","description":"Osaka-Kansai","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":3,"flight_location":"PEK","description":"Beijing","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":4,"flight_location":"HGH","description":"Hangzhou","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":5,"flight_location":"PVG","description":"Shanghai","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":6,"flight_location":"SZX","description":"Shenzhen","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":7,"flight_location":"DPS","description":"Bali","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":8,"flight_location":"CGK","description":"Jakarta","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":9,"flight_location":"DMK","description":"Bangkok","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0}]
```

Here is my code:

```
let fakeData = [{"location_id":1,"flight_location":"KUL","description":"Kuala Lumpur","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":2,"flight_location":"KIX","description":"Osaka-Kansai","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":3,"flight_location":"PEK","description":"Beijing","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":4,"flight_location":"HGH","description":"Hangzhou","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":5,"flight_location":"PVG","description":"Shanghai","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":6,"flight_location":"SZX","description":"Shenzhen","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":7,"flight_location":"DPS","description":"Bali","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":8,"flight_location":"CGK","description":"Jakarta","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":9,"flight_location":"DMK","description":"Bangkok","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0}];

let flights = {};


fetch(link) //link is the api link which I use to fetch the data
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json(); //In here I parse it
    }).then(function(json) {
        /*flights = fakeData;     Causes same error. Run this only to test when api is down */  
        flights = json; // Same error. Set our flights map to the parsed json which is the map     
    }).catch(function(ex) {
      console.log('parsing failed', ex);
    });
```

Console output:

[image]

This is from the React library. Btw , I'm not really familiar with the codes in their library.

My components:

**FlightList**

```
const FlightList = ({flights, deleteFlight}) => {
    return (
        <table className="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {flights.map(flight =>
                    <FlightListRow key={flight.location_id} flight={flight}/>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
};
```

**FlightListRow**

```
const FlightListRow = ({flight}) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td><Link to={'/editflight/' + flight.location_id}>{flight.location_id}</Link></td>
            <td><Link to={'/editflight/' + flight.location_id}>{flight.flight_location}</Link></td>
            <td><Link to={'/editflight/' + flight.location_id}>{flight.description}</Link></td>
        </tr>
    );
};
```

Comment: A valid `JSON` have the property sorrounded with quotes like this: `[{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]` . So this is normal that parsing it fails. To check the validaty of your `JSON, you can use a website like this one: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: how does that address duplicate keys?

Comment: my json is valid, I just checked. So I set it to my `mapA` and still getting the same or duplicate key error. Here's my result: http://i.imgur.com/760Dy9w.png?1

Comment: please add the relevant data in **text form** to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz I added the data

Comment: please add the part of the code where the error occurs.

Comment: For the sake of being explicit, @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I would like to add to your comment:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes

Comment: @NinaScholz I've added the code

Comment: @JoshuaRajandiran Could you post exact console output with the error message. It doesn't seem like any data you have posted could cause the error. Actually `JSON.parse` is tollerant to duplicate keys `JSON.parse('{"a": 1, "a": 2}'); //no error`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I've added the console output

Comment: @JoshuaRajandiran Well, now it is obvious the error has nothing to do with the code you have posted. It comes from somewhere else where you are using the data. And react requires your keys to be unique but your data has the same `flight_id` which I assume you were using as a key.

Comment: Could you add component code that uses the data?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a react error , this means in your react component , you have an array of components and you are using same key on two or more components

```
       {flights.map((flight,index) =>
            <FlightListRow key={index} flight={flight}/>
        )}
```

Comment: I've added the components that I use. Which part does my error come from?

Comment: <FlightListRow key={flight.location_id} flight={flight}/>
I am sure location_id must be duplicating
You can replace it index
<FlightListRow key={index} flight={flight}/>

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. Got an error that says 'index' is not defined.

Comment: See the updated code, you need it add index to map function too

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Was having a headache for days and I remember a 100k rep guy kept asking me too much questions and he downvoted my old question because he expects me to know everything. I'm glad you helped with in solving this problem I had. Thanks again :)