# Can't correctly parse JSON fixture in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, testunit

I'm using Test::Unit in an old Rails app (3.2.22) and I'm trying to test a service class that hits an external api.

I'm using webmock and trying to get a json file fixture working, but I keep getting parsing errors from the json file.

My test stub looks like this:

```rb
response_data = fixture_file_upload('easypost/order_response.json')
stub_request(:post, 'https://api.easypost.com/v2/orders').
  to_return(:status => 200, :body => File.read(response_data))
```

My `order_response.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  'mode':'test',
  'reference':'Order',
  'is_return':false,
  'options':{'currency':'USD','label_date':null}
}
```

When I run the tests, I get a parse error:

```rb
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{'mode':'test','reference':'Order','is_return':false,'options':{'currency':'USD','label_date':null}}'
```

What is going on?

**UPDATE:**

Got it working by using double quotes in the JSON file:

```
{
  "mode":"test",
  "reference":"Order",
  "is_return":false,
  "options":{"currency":"USD","label_date":null}
}
```

Could anyone explain why this is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine specification](http://json.org):

> A *string* is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

and and *object* is a set of key/value pairs where the keys are strings:

[image]

That means that this:

```
{
  'mode':'test',
  'reference':'Order',
  'is_return':false,
  'options':{'currency':'USD','label_date':null}
}
```

is not JSON because JSON strings use double quotes and only double quotes, that's just something that sort of looks like JSON. When you switch to double quotes for your strings:

```
{
  "mode":"test",
  "reference":"Order",
  "is_return":false,
  "options":{"currency":"USD","label_date":null}
}
```

then you have JSON and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

> This is to make it simpler and to avoid having to have another escape method for javascript reserved keywords

I think this post might be helpful in understanding the need for quotations (and also where I found the above quote): [JSON Spec - does the key have to be surrounded with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)