# Can't do JSON.parse on data from SQL Server

Tags: javascript, json

I have a query that gets data from SQL Server, and in one of the fields we are storing JSON as a `varchar(max)`. The issue is that when I try to get the data out in my Node app and do a `JSON.parse`, it's not working. Here's what I've tried:

```
console.log(data.attr);
    // "{ firstName: 'Preston', lastName: 'Lamb' }"
JSON.parse(data.attr) 
    // Invalid expression: unexpected end of input (get this on one item)
    // invalid expression: unexpected token f in json at position 2 (and this on the other)
newJsonStr = JSON.stringify(data.attr)
    // ""{ firstName: 'Preston', lastName: 'Lamb' }""
newJson = JSON.parse(newJsonStr)
    // "{ firstName: 'Preston', lastName: 'Lamb' }"
```

[image]

None of this is really complicated stuff...it should be easy to JSON.parse and/or JSON.stringify, but it doesn't work. Any ideas at all?

Comment: That is not JSON. In JSON both the keys and string values are wrapped in *double* quotes.

Comment: From the JSON spec: '*A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, **wrapped in double quotes**, using backslash escapes*'

Comment: You can try to `eval` it instead: `eval("(" + data.attr + ")");`

Comment: You should fix the code that fills in the database so it's correct JSON.

Answer (score 1):

What the other commentator meant by it's not JSON is that your keys need to be wrapped in quotes to be parsed as JSON.

[JSON Spec - does the key have to be surrounded with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/json-spec-does-the-key-have-to-be-surrounded-with-quotes)

Comment: Whenever I encounter a JSON error like this, I will always verify the data using JSON Lint, available:


Website version: [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com)


NPM CLI version: [npmjs.com/package/jsonlint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonlint)

Comment: Okay, when I inserted manually into the database I forgot that. But putting double quotes around attributes and values, and even escaping them, still causes issues. Just trying to parse the response is where the `invalid expression: unexpected end of json input` error came from, and when you `JSON.stringify` it first it adds doesn't do anything.

Comment: @StevenStark After using JSON lint, I could see that one of those fields was missing a double quote, and so it wasn't parsing correctly. I'll have to work on the other field to make sure to add it properly to the database. Thanks!

Comment: @pjlamb12 Don't try to create JSON by hand. Most languages have library functions to create JSON, you should use it.