# Why the key is displaying as string?

Tags: java, spring-boot, browser, hashmap, jersey

I am using jersey with springboot. Below is my code and response i get.

Code:

```
@Component
@Path("/books")
public class BookController {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Map getAllBooks() {

        Map jsonObject = new HashMap<>();
        jsonObject.put(1,1);
        jsonObject.put("2","string2");
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Response in chrome browser :

> {"1":1,"2":"string2"}

As you can see, the first object's key is an integer but it shows as string in the browser. how to display the key as an integer in the browser.

Comment: the key is always a string in a hash map if you don't set another type. but all keys have to be the same type

Comment: [Do the JSON keys have to be surrounded by quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949449/2587435)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), the key of a JSON object is **always** a string. Quoting the RFC:

> An **object structure** is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more **name/value pairs** (or members).  A **name is a
> string**.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
> from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
> name.  The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

So the answer to your question is: you can't.