# How to return number and newline with JSON

Tags: json, newline

I want to return a number and a new line

```
{ data : "3
"}
```

But every time, I try to do this it is considered invalid

[image]

**Update**

My parser tool tries to do things with Newlines. Here is the complete screenshot:

[image]

** Update 2**

This is with jsonlint.com

[image]

Comment: The error in the screenshot, if you read it carefully, is nothing to do with the newline...it's talking about "position 2" (i.e. the second character of the JSON) and the `d` character (which is of course the second one). Property names in JSON must have double quotes around them. So `{ "data":`...etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `data` is not a valid key (check https://www.json.org/ or [Do the JSON keys have to be surrounded by quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/do-the-json-keys-have-to-be-surrounded-by-quotes)), you need to use quotes for keys in order to have valid syntax. Also you need to add `\n` for a new line character:

```
{ "data": "3\n"}
```

Comment: That does not work either. I should have included in my question that I tried and failed on that.

Comment: @JamesAMohler: Can you post the link to the validator? https://jsonlint.com/ considers this valid for example.

Comment: Works fine with `{ "data": "3\n"}` ;)

Comment: Not on jsonlint.com nor on Chrome

Comment: Your updates are still missing the quotes around `data`! You need to use `"data"` ...

Answer (score -1):

I pasted this into the console without an error:
`{ "data" : "3\n"}`

Testing one step further:

```
a = { "data" : "3\n"}
a.data + "hello" // pasted into the console
```

produced this:

```
3
hello
```

Comment: 1. Your example has data unambiguously as a string. Strings work OK
2. JSON is a subset of Javascript. It does not allow concatenation like that

Comment: The question is about JSON, not JavaScript

Comment: Right. It should be "data", I should have added quotes.  However the questions only asked "I want to return a number and a new line".  I was just trying to show the use of "\n" to return the number with the newline.