# Potential Typescript compiler bug?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out if this is typescript compiler bug or a feature

```
export interface Player {
    Name: string;
    Bio?: string;
    Type: 'casual' | 'pro' | 'titan' | 'nolife', 'YouDidNotDeclare';
    Online: boolean;
}
```

So here is the thing, it compiles just fine. Until you try to use the interface as such

```
 let player : Player = {Name : 'Oldum', Bio : 'Just Chilling', Type: 'casual', Online : false }
```

You expect the above to work just fine but then you get the error;
*Property ''YouDidNotDeclare'' is missing in type*

Adding the said property **YouDidNotDeclare** clears the said error but here is the thing i realized,

On the interface declaration, I missed a '|' for a ',' on the 'Type' property.

```
  export interface Player {
        Name: string;
        Bio?: string;
        Type: 'casual' | 'pro' | 'titan' | 'nolife' | 'YouDidNotDeclare';
        Online: boolean;
    }
```

Now my question is, is it a bug or feature and if intended, in what situation will I need to use such a feature?

Comment: "You expect the above to work just fine" - no, I don't. The comma is immediately visible and a comma in a type-definition (including an `interface` definition) is a member-separator.

Comment: This question isn't about the [The Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API), so I removed that tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a compiler bug; it's a set of features that you are not intending to use.

---

First, in `interface` and other purely type-level object type definitions, the compiler interprets a comma (`,`) as a separator between members, just like a semicolon (`;`):

```
// the following interfaces are equivalent
interface Semicolons { foo: string; bar: number; }
interface Commas { foo: string, bar: number }
```

That means `'nolife'` is considered the end of the `Type` member declaration.

---

Second, you are allowed to put property names inside quotation marks:

```
// the following two interfaces are equivalent
interface Bare { foo: string }
interface Quoted { "foo": string }
```

This is helpful when an object type has a property that isn't a valid JavaScript identifier, like `"uses-dashes"` or even just to be consistent with [JSON specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949449/do-the-json-keys-have-to-be-surrounded-by-quotes).

That means `YouDidNotDeclare` is considered to be the name of a property.

---

Finally, TypeScript does not require type annotations.  For variable or function parameters declared without explicit type annotations, sometimes there is enough contextual information for the compiler to *infer* a reasonable type for them:

```
const foo = { a: 123 };
// foo inferred as { a: number; }

[1, 2, 3].map(x => x * 3);
// x inferred as number
```

Such implicit types are often quite desirable and it's considered good practice for you to leave off type annotations in situations like this where the inferred types are what you intended.

But there are other situations in which there is not enough contextual information for reasonable type inference.  When this happens, the compiler gives up and infers [the `any` "type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```
// the following two interfaces are equivalent
interface Explicit { foo: any }
interface Implicit { foo }
```

---

Thus your `interface` is equivalent to the following:

```
export interface Hater {
    Name: string;
    Bio?: string;
    Type: 'casual' | 'pro' | 'titan' | 'nolife';
    YouDidNotDeclare: any;
    Online: boolean;
}
```

which is definitely *not* what you intended.

---

In fact, it is *so rarely useful* for the compiler to implicitly infer an `any` type like it does with `YouDidNotDeclare`, that there's a recommended compiler option [`--noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) which produces a compiler warning whenever this happens.  This compiler option can be enabled by itself, or along with a whole suite of stronger type checking options via the [`--strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) compiler option.

If you enable those, your interface definition will immediately warn you that something weird has happened:

```
Type: 'casual' | 'pro' | 'titan' | 'nolife', 'YouDidNotDeclare'; // error!
// ----------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Member ''YouDidNotDeclare'' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Which should allow you to fix the definition to the version you intended it to be.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeMCGAuGBGAJgGYYBfAbgCgB6a+RGASzDgFMAnd1gEywnSy4wAVwC2AIw7kylSgG08AGhgFlRALoA6UZgAOACgAeKAHwxjAKhhEAlFVrmmLDl16Z+IiR1kOoAC1Z6ABsgkAB3ZgBzGCgwpGYoDjhMYFZ+TC4YVgBHYUYAN0wg1jAoSgSklMCAZVZRRlBQyAEEEFxodijpcQyhMUl2aVJy0srUmABhEFEdfgxW9qhOsEjlHvY+r3ZlYZo6f0CEEPComLinRPZk1PTMnLzC4tKRy+vAgCEMwPnEReXo4YVK5VGAARWEIESvAwACJWjC-qddr4AsFQhEVmd4qNgTcsHdcgUiiUykC3jAAKKGXRBBqMWA-NpYMAATxkZJBAElRDS6Qz6EhkftUUd0adYtjXlVboF7kSnmVWNSQOxYBzxgAFIKYFkcdCUGCGmAAOUwolYiJWVCNMHejBAAH5LZFrUaACos3QWmAAcmA7mERR9MAAPr7dOwQMGwz6oPTMGBo76wCBaWwfcofQBNEDCAAijG4xshedYwG1XB90gcLhVAEIDUaHABaVtt9sdztd7vtswAPwHg6Hw8HjcNDgAsnUBr7s7mC0WS2WK6wfcHGDzacB6UE2X53MzfQmWcGoJ7WJoxzAAPJgWlgb3iRDFBNUYZK3QqtU48kACUwlz6japrms6rqGnajpgVeHpergfoBkGobhpGSaxvGibIT6KZpqu4EwDm+aFsWUCluWXy4Me+G3vej7Pqwr6ULsQA)

Comment: So (Comma) ',' on the type declaration is seen as a (Semi-colon) ';' by the compiler and just infers YouDidNotDeclare as 'any' . Great clarification.